# Convert an array of primitive longs into a List of Longs

Tags: java, arrays, collections, boxing

This may be a bit of an easy, headdesk sort of question, but my first attempt surprisingly completely failed to work.  I wanted to take an array of primitive longs and turn it into a list, which I attempted to do like this:

```
long[] input = someAPI.getSomeLongs();
List<Long> inputAsList = Arrays.asList(input); //Total failure to even compile!
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: I think we've had the same question for ints, haven't we?

Comment: @Tom, yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I found it convenient to do using apache commons lang ArrayUtils ([JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toObject(long[])), [Maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/latest))

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
...
long[] input = someAPI.getSomeLongs();
Long[] inputBoxed = ArrayUtils.toObject(input);
List<Long> inputAsList = Arrays.asList(inputBoxed);
```

it also has the reverse API

```
long[] backToPrimitive = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(objectArray);
```

**EDIT:** updated to provide a complete conversion to a list as suggested by comments and other fixes.

Comment: Considering that this creates an _array_ of Longs, _not a List_, it doesn't answer OP's question and gets my downvote.  How the heck did this get 56 upvotes and the coveted "check"???

Comment: Because people can easily do `Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(input))` probably.

Comment: I agree with @user949300.  This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This answer should be updated to provide a complete conversion to a list. However, it is an efficient step towards the solution.

Comment: @JimJeffers - thanks, updated to included the complete conversion. Since the OP included `List<Long> = Arrays.asList(inputBoxed)` in their question I found it redundant to repeat it as I thought it was obvious, I guess I was wrong...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - well, I'll be... good catch. The reason is that I copied it 1:1 from the question without even looking, but that's no excuse :) (in any case I fixed the question as well so it won't distract) thanks! (God knows how many times I saw the question and didn't notice it...)

Comment: I tried it and it points to error in the second line. Java doesn't recognize ArrayUtils. Is it because we have to use streams from now?

Comment: @Talgat - you will need to add it as a dependency :) I updated the answer with some info on how (maven dep, import statement)

Comment: That's why complexities are asked in interview questions. You are iterating through the list two times. I'd rather prefer to iterate through the arr and make it a list to avoid two iterations.

Comment: @RaviSoni yeah, I see your point, but 1) it has the same big O, iterating on the same list twice is still O(n) and 2) 99% use cases this would be a major premature optimization in my opinion.

Answer (score 135):

Since Java 8 you can now use streams for that:

```
long[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<Long> list = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Nice one! Unfortunately, and somewhat mysteriously, the `stream` function is only defined for `int[]`, `long[]` and `double[]`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `LongStream.of(arr).boxed()...`.

Comment: `Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());` Unfortunately this can only return `List<Object>`

Comment: No bulky libraries for a simple task, no loops. Great answer.

Comment: @SenthilkumarAnnadurai: No, that's incorrect, this solution returns a `List<Long>`.

Answer (score 36):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

List<Long> longs = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(new long[] {1,2,3,4}));
```

Comment: An explanation of what this does and whether this is a third party library would be helpful.

Answer (score 35):

[hallidave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754294/convert-an-array-of-primitive-longs-into-a-list-of-longs/754324#754324) and [jpalecek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754294/convert-an-array-of-primitive-longs-into-a-list-of-longs/754325#754325) have the right idea—iterating over an array—but they don't take advantage of a feature provided by `ArrayList`: since *the size of the list is known* in this case, you should specify it when you create the `ArrayList`.

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>(input.length);
for (long n : input)
  list.add(n);
```

This way, no unnecessary arrays are created only to be discarded by the `ArrayList` because they turn out to be too short, and no empty "slots" are wasted because `ArrayList` overestimated its space requirements. Of course, if you continue to add elements to the list, a new backing array will be needed.

Comment: I tend to leave out the length specification unless the code is proven to be part of a performance hot spot or the array is expected to be extremely large.  I think that leaving out the length makes the code  slightly more readable.

Answer (score 20):

A bit more verbose, but this works:

```
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for (long value : input) {
        list.add(value);
    }
```

In your example it appears that Arrays.asList() is interpreting the input as list of long[] arrays instead of a list of Longs.  A bit surprising, for sure.  Autoboxing just doesn't work the way you want it to in this case.

Comment: That's the best option if one needs to do it for older Java versions than Java 8.

Answer (score 18):

As another possibility, [the Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) provides this as [`Longs.asList()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Longs.html#asList-long...-), with similar utility classes for the other primitive types.

```
import com.google.common.primitives.Longs;

long[] input = someAPI.getSomeLongs();
List<Long> output = Longs.asList(input);
```

Answer (score 9):

<sup>The question asked about how to turn an array into a list. Most answers so far showed how to create a *new* list with the same contents as the array, or referred to third-party libraries. However, there are simple, built-in options for this sort of conversion. Some of them have already been sketched in other answers (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17983559/3182664)). But I'd like to point out and elaborate certain degrees of freedom for the implementation here, and show the potential benefits, drawbacks and caveats.</sup>

There are at least two important distinctions to be made:

- Whether the resulting list should be a **view** on the array or whether it should be a **new** list
- Whether the resulting list should be **modifiable** or not

The options will be summarized here quickly, and a complete example program is shown at the bottom of this answer.

---

**Creating a new list versus creating a *view* on the array**

When the result should be a **new** list, then one of the approaches from the other answers may be used:

```
List<Long> list = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But one should consider the drawbacks of doing this: An array with 1000000 `long` values will occupy roughly 8 Megabytes of memory. The new list will *also* occupy roughly 8 Megabytes. And of course, the full array has to be traversed while creating this list. In many cases, creating a new list is simply not necessary. Instead, it is sufficient to create a **view** on the array:

```
// This occupies ca. 8 MB
long array[] = { /* 1 million elements */ }

// Properly implemented, this list will only occupy a few bytes,
// and the array does NOT have to be traversed, meaning that this
// operation has nearly ZERO memory- and processing overhead:
List<Long> list = asList(array);
```

<sup>(See the example at the bottom for an implementation of the `toList` method)</sup>

The implication of having a *view* on the array are that changes in the array will be visible in the list:

```
long array[] = { 12, 34, 56, 78 };
List<Long> list = asList(array);

System.out.println(list.get(1)); // This will print 34

// Modify the array contents:
array[1] = 12345;

System.out.println(list.get(1)); // This will now print 12345!
```

Fortunately, creating a copy (that is, a **new** list that is not affected by modifications in the array) from the view is trivial:

```
List<Long> copy = new ArrayList<Long>(asList(array));
```

Now, this is a true copy, equivalent to what is achieved with the stream-based solution that was shown above.

---

**Creating a *modifiable* view or an *unmodifiable* view**

In many cases, it will be sufficient when the list is *read-only*. The contents of the resulting list will often not be modified, but only passed to downstream processing that only reads the list.

Allowing for modifications of the list raises some questions:

```
long array[] = { 12, 34, 56, 78 };
List<Long> list = asList(array);

list.set(2, 34567);           // Should this be possible?
System.out.println(array[2]); // Should this print 34567?
list.set(3, null);            // What should happen here?
list.add(99999);              // Should this be possible?
```

It is possible to create a list view on the array that is *modifiable*. This means that changes in the list, like setting a new value at a certain index, will be visible in the array.

But it is not possible to create a list view that is *structurally modifiable*. This means that it is not possible to do operations that affect the *size* of the list. This is simply because the size of the underlying *array* cannot be changed.

---

The following is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the different implementation options, and the possible ways of using the resulting lists:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.RandomAccess;

public class PrimitiveArraysAsLists
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long array[] = { 12, 34, 56, 78 };

        // Create VIEWS on the given array
        List<Long> list = asList(array);
        List<Long> unmodifiableList = asUnmodifiableList(array);

        // If a NEW list is desired (and not a VIEW on the array), this
        // can be created as well:
        List<Long> copy = new ArrayList<Long>(asList(array));

        System.out.println("array           : " + Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println("list            : " + list);
        System.out.println("unmodifiableList: " + unmodifiableList);
        System.out.println("copy            : " + copy);        

        // Modify a value in the array. The changes will be visible
        // in the list and the unmodifiable list, but not in
        // the copy.
        System.out.println("Changing value at index 1 of the array...");
        array[1] = 34567;

        System.out.println("array           : " + Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println("list            : " + list);
        System.out.println("unmodifiableList: " + unmodifiableList);
        System.out.println("copy            : " + copy);        

        // Modify a value of the list. The changes will be visible
        // in the array and the unmodifiable list, but not in
        // the copy.
        System.out.println("Changing value at index 2 of the list...");
        list.set(2, 56789L);

        System.out.println("array           : " + Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println("list            : " + list);
        System.out.println("unmodifiableList: " + unmodifiableList);
        System.out.println("copy            : " + copy);        


        // Certain operations are not supported:
        try
        {
            // Throws an UnsupportedOperationException: This list is 
            // unmodifiable, because the "set" method is not implemented
            unmodifiableList.set(2, 23456L);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Expected: " + e);
        }

        try
        {
            // Throws an UnsupportedOperationException: The size of the
            // backing array cannot be changed
            list.add(90L);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Expected: " + e);
        }


        try
        {
            // Throws a NullPointerException: The value 'null' cannot be  
            // converted to a primitive 'long' value for the underlying array
            list.set(2, null);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Expected: " + e);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Returns an unmodifiable view on the given array, as a list.
     * Changes in the given array will be visible in the returned
     * list.
     *  
     * @param array The array
     * @return The list view
     */
    private static List<Long> asUnmodifiableList(long array[])
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(array);
        class ResultList extends AbstractList<Long> implements RandomAccess
        {
            @Override
            public Long get(int index)
            {
                return array[index];
            }

            @Override
            public int size()
            {
                return array.length;
            }
        };
        return new ResultList();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a view on the given array, as a list. Changes in the given 
     * array will be visible in the returned list, and vice versa. The
     * list does not allow for <i>structural modifications</i>, meaning
     * that it is not possible to change the size of the list.
     *  
     * @param array The array
     * @return The list view
     */
    private static List<Long> asList(long array[])
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(array);
        class ResultList extends AbstractList<Long> implements RandomAccess
        {
            @Override
            public Long get(int index)
            {
                return array[index];
            }

            @Override
            public Long set(int index, Long element)
            {
                long old = array[index];
                array[index] = element;
                return old;
            }

            @Override
            public int size()
            {
                return array.length;
            }
        };
        return new ResultList();
    }

}
```

The output of the example is shown here:

```
array           : [12, 34, 56, 78]
list            : [12, 34, 56, 78]
unmodifiableList: [12, 34, 56, 78]
copy            : [12, 34, 56, 78]
Changing value at index 1 of the array...
array           : [12, 34567, 56, 78]
list            : [12, 34567, 56, 78]
unmodifiableList: [12, 34567, 56, 78]
copy            : [12, 34, 56, 78]
Changing value at index 2 of the list...
array           : [12, 34567, 56789, 78]
list            : [12, 34567, 56789, 78]
unmodifiableList: [12, 34567, 56789, 78]
copy            : [12, 34, 56, 78]
Expected: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Expected: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Expected: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no automatic conversion from array of primitive type to array of their boxed reference types. You can only do

```
long[] input = someAPI.getSomeLongs();
List<Long> lst = new ArrayList<Long>();

for(long l : input) lst.add(l);
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way with Java 8.

```
long[] input = someAPI.getSomeLongs();
LongStream.of(input).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm writing a small library for these problems:

```
long[] input = someAPI.getSomeLongs();
List<Long> = $(input).toList();
```

In the case you care check it [here](https://bitbucket.org/adamldavis/dollar/wiki/Home).

Comment: nice library! at first, I wasn't sure it was Java... I like the JQuery style

Answer (score 5):

Another [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30636289/330457) with Java 8.

```java
final long[] a = new long[]{1L, 2L};
final List<Long> l = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: When returning the list (not assigning it), I found I had to do: `Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.<Long>toList());`

Comment: This is identical to [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23117638).

Answer (score 3):

Combining Pavel and Tom's answers we get this

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> List<T> asList(final Object array) {
        if (!array.getClass().isArray())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not an array");
        return new AbstractList<T>() {
            @Override
            public T get(int index) {
                return (T) Array.get(array, index);
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                return Array.getLength(array);
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want similar semantics to `Arrays.asList` then you'll need to write (or use someone else's) customer implementation of `List` (probably through `AbstractList`. It should have much the same implementation as `Arrays.asList`, only box and unbox values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [transmorph](http://transmorph.sourceforge.net) :

```
Transmorph transmorph = new Transmorph(new DefaultConverters());
List<Long> = transmorph.convert(new long[] {1,2,3,4}, new TypeReference<List<Long>>() {});
```

It also works if source is an array of ints for example.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old enough, but... you can also write your own conversion method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> List<T> toList(Object... items) {

    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    if (items.length == 1 && items[0].getClass().isArray()) {
        int length = Array.getLength(items[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Object element = Array.get(items[0], i);
            T item = (T)element;
            list.add(item);
        }
    } else {
        for (Object i : items) {
            T item = (T)i;
            list.add(item);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

After you include it using static import, possible usages could be:

```
    long[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    List<Long> list = toList(array);
```

or

```
    List<Long> list = toList(1l, 2l, 3l, 4l, 5l, 6l, 7l, 8l, 9l);
```

Comment: regarding: `catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) { /* Finished getting array elements */ }`, you are a terrible person.

Comment: Hey, man, thanks for that! 
Your ironical remark made me find a better solution - getting the array's length through Array.getLength().

Comment: Fantastic! I'm glad my sardonic attitude led to progress instead of just general bad feelings all around :)  Really, it's not a good idea to use exceptions except in very unusual conditions. They're surprisingly expensive to create. This new version is much, MUCH faster.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to create a new List and add all the values to it (via for loop or streams), I have been working on really big arrays and get poor performance. Therefore I created my own easy to use primitive array wrapper class.

Example:

```
long[] arr = new long[] {1,2,3};
PrimativeList<Long> list = PrimativeList.create(arr); // detects long[] and returns PrimativeList<Long>

System.out.println(list.get(1)); // prints: 2
list.set(2, 15);
System.out.println(arr[2]);  // prints: 15
```

Get it here:
https://github.com/Sf298/Sauds-Toolbox/blob/master/src/main/java/PrimitiveArrayWrapper/PrimitiveList.java

NOTE: I haven't fully tested it yet, so let me know if  you find any bugs/issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LongStream` for that

```
List<Long> longs = LongStream.of(new long[]{1L, 2L, 3L}).boxed()
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```