# Arrays.asList() not working as it should?

Tags: java, arrays, list, variadic-functions

I have a float[] and i would like to get a list with the same elements. I could do the ugly thing of adding them one by one but i wanted to use the Arrays.asList method. There is a problem though. This works:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
```

But this does not.

```
int[] ints = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(ints);
```

The asList method accepts a varargs parameter which to the extends of my knowledge is a "shorthand" for an array.

Questions:

- Why does the second piece of code returns a `List<int[]>` but not `List<int>`.
- Is there a way to correct it?
- Why doesn't autoboxing work here; i.e. `int[]` to `Integer[]`?

Comment: Btw: what happened to the `float[]` array?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

How about this?

```
Integer[] ints = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(ints);
```

Comment: Beat me, but it would be better with an explanation also.

Comment: unbelievable... It works with reference but not with primitive types :D thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Hm but is there an easy way to convert an int[] to Integer[]? The thing is i get my array via a method call and i cannot change it.

Comment: @Savvas: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/java-convert-int-to-integer or Jon Skeet's answer here. Libraries like Apache Commons Lang or Guava will be of some help.

Comment: Can warning be overcome *Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<Integer>* ?

Comment: Array.asList works only with Objects? Not Primitive array?

Answer (score 96):

There's no such thing as a `List<int>` in Java - generics don't support primitives.

Autoboxing only happens for a single element, not for *arrays* of primitives.

As for how to correct it - there are various libraries with oodles of methods for doing things like this. There's no way round this, and I don't *think* there's anything to make it easier within the JDK. Some will *wrap* a primitive array in a list of the wrapper type (so that boxing happens on access), others will iterate through the original array to create an independent copy, boxing as they go. Make sure you know which you're using.

(EDIT: I'd been assuming that the starting point of an `int[]` was non-negotiable. If you can start with an `Integer[]` then you're well away :)

Just for one example of a helper library, and to plug [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) a bit, there's [`com.google.common.primitive.Ints.asList`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList-int...-).

Comment: Why does "Autoboxing only happens for a single element, not for arrays of primitives.". What do you think is the reason for this design decision?

Comment: @Geek: Well what would you suggest as an alternative? It would be odd for a `double[]` to be automatically converted to a `Double[]` by copying all the elements - such that a cast of a reference type would effectively clone the data, unlike every other operation in Java. If you're suggesting that a `Double[]` should be able to be backed by a `double[]` in a "view" sort of way, that has other issues such as how you store null references and again the difference between this and other arrays. I think it was the right decision.

Comment: with java 8 you can use stream api: List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(new int[]{1,2,3}).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());, a bit verbose though

Comment: One of these Guava functions that should have been added to Java a long way back. Horrible type juggling with primitive types is unfortunately not going away soon.

Comment: Warning: lists returned by `Ints.asList` do not support `add()` or related methods

Answer (score 21):

Because java arrays are objects and `Arrays.asList()` treats your int array as a **single** argument in the varargs list.

Comment: @mmyers In fact, that's what this question is all about. +1 for ChssPly76

Answer (score 17):

Enter Java 8, and you can do following to collect in a boxed Array:

```
Integer[] boxedInts = IntStream.of(ints).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Or this to collect in a boxed List

```
List<Integer> boxedInts = IntStream.of(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, this only works for `int[]`, `long[]`, and `double[]`. This will not work for `byte[]`.

Note that `Arrays.stream(ints)` and `IntStream.of(ints)` are equivalent. So earlier two examples can also be rewritten as:

```
Integer[] boxedIntArray = Arrays.stream(ints).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
List<Integer> boxedIntList = Arrays.stream(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This last form could be favored as it omits a primitive specific subtype of `Stream`. However, internally it is still a bunch of overloaded's which in this case still create a `IntStream` internally.

Comment: You need to cast the result from `toArray()` since it returns `Object[]`

Comment: nope .. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray--

Comment: Ok. You are right. Type at that point is `Stream<Integer>` and not `IntStream`. I have fixed it however by using `toArray(Integer[]::new)` instead. Maybe simply typecasting here would be better?

Comment: This is actually a *different* overloaded `toArray()` implementation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) that uses a _generator function_  and does the job properly.
It's better to avoid typecasting where you can..

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not with `Arrays.asList()`. The problem is that you expect autoboxing to work on an array - and it doesn't. In the first case, the compiler autoboxes the individual ints before it looks at what they're used for. In the second case, you first put them into an int array (no autoboxing necessary) and then pass that to `Arrays.asList()` (not autoboxing possible).

Answer (score 4):

`Arrays.asList(T... a)` effectively takes a `T[]` which will match any array of true objects (subclasses of `Object`) as an array. The only thing that won't match like that is an array of primitives, since primitive types do not derive from `Object`. So an `int[]` is not an `Object[]`.

What happens then is that the varags mechanism kicks in and treats it as if you had passed a single object, and creates a single element array of that type. So you pass an `int[][]` (here, `T` is `int[]`) and end up with a 1-element `List<int[]>` which is not what you want.

You still have some pretty good options though:

### Guava's `Int.asList(int[])` Adapter

If your project already uses guava, it's as simple as using the adapter Guava provides:  [Int.asList()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList%28int...%29).  There is a similar adapter for each primitive type in the associated class, e.g., `Booleans` for `boolean`, etc.

```
int foo[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
Iterable<Integer> fooBar = Ints.asList(foo);
for(Integer i : fooBar) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it creates a thin wrapper around the existing array, so the creation of the wrapper is constant time (doesn't depend on the size of the array), and the storage required is only a small constant amount (less than 100 bytes) in addition to the underlying integer array.

The downside is that accessing each element requires a boxing operation of the underlying `int`, and setting requires unboxing. This may result in a large amount of transient memory allocation if you access the list heavily.  If you access each object many times on average, it may be better to use an implementation that boxes the objects once and stores them as `Integer`. The solution below does that.

### Java 8 IntStream

In Java 8, you can use the `Arrays.stream(int[])` method to turn an `int` array into a `Stream`. Depending on your use case, you may be able to use the stream directly, e.g., to do something with each element with [`forEach(IntConsumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#forEach-java.util.function.IntConsumer-). In that case, this solution is very fast and doesn't incur any boxing or unboxing at all, and does not create any copy of the underlying array.

Alternately, if you really need a `List<Integer>`, you can use `stream.boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674624/how-do-i-convert-a-java-8-intstream-to-a-list). The downside of that approach is that it fully boxes every element in the list, which might increase its memory footprint by nearly an order of magnitude, it create a new `Object[]` to hold all the boxed elements. If you subsequently use the list heavily and need `Integer` objects rather than `int`s, this may pay off, but it's something to be aware of.

Answer (score 4):

> Why doesn't autoboxing work here; i.e. int[] to Integer[]?

While autoboxing will convert an `int` to an `Integer`, it will not convert an `int[]` to an `Integer[]`.

Why not?

The simple (but unsatisfying) answer is because that is what the JLS says.  (You can check it if you like.)

The real answer is fundamental to what autoboxing is doing and why it is safe.

When you autobox `1` anywhere in your code, you get the same `Integer` object.  This is not true for all `int` values (due to the limited size of the `Integer` autoboxing cache), but if you use `equals` to compare `Integer` objects you get the "right" answer.

Basically `N == N` is always true and `new Integer(N).equals(new Integer(N))` is always true.  Furthermore, these two things *remain* true ... assuming that you stick with Pure Java code.

Now consider this:

```
int[] x = new int[]{1};
int[] y = new int[]{1};
```

Are these equal?  No!  `x == y` is false and `x.equals(y)` is false!   But why? Because:

```
y[0] = 2;
```

In other words, two arrays with the same type, size and content are always distinguishable because Java arrays are mutable.

The "promise" of autoboxing is that it is OK to do because the results are indistinguishable<sup>1</sup>.   But, because all arrays are fundamentally distinguishable because of the definition of `equals` for arrays AND array mutability.  So, if autoboxing of arrays of primitive types *was* permitted, it would undermine the "promise".

---

<sup>1 - ..... provided that you don't use `==` to test if autoboxed values are equal.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you pass an `int[]` to `Arrays.asList()`, the list created will be `List<int[]>`,  which is not vaild in java, not the correct `List<Integer>`.

I think you are expecting `Arrays.asList()` to auto-box your ints, which as you have seen, it won't.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to convert `int[]` to `Integer[]`, you have to copy values

---

```
int[] tab = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
List<Integer> list = ArraysHelper.asList(tab);
```

---

```
public static List<Integer> asList(int[] a) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length && list.add(a[i]); i++);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [`IntList`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/primitive/IntList.html) as the type and the `IntLists` [factory](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/factory/primitive/package-summary.html) from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) to create the collection directly from an array of `int` values. This removes the need for any boxing of `int` to `Integer`.

```
IntList intList1 = IntLists.mutable.with(1,2,3,4,5);
int[] ints = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
IntList intList2 = IntLists.mutable.with(ints);
Assert.assertEquals(intList1, intList2);
```

Eclipse Collections has support for mutable and immutable primitive `List` as well as `Set`, `Bag`, `Stack` and `Map`.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a primitive type. Arrays.asList() accept generic type T which only works on reference types (object types), not on primitives. Since int[] as a whole is an object it can be added as a single element.