# how to use addall() method of collections?

Tags: java, list, collections, merge

i need to use it to merge two ordered list of objects.

Comment: What do you mean by merge? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 20):

From the API:

> [`addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29): Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this collection (optional operation).

Here's an example using `List`, which is an ordered collection:

```
    List<Integer> nums1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,-1);
    List<Integer> nums2 = Arrays.asList(4,5,6);

    List<Integer> allNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    allNums.addAll(nums1);
    allNums.addAll(nums2);
    System.out.println(allNums);
    // prints "[1, 2, -1, 4, 5, 6]"
```

---

#### On `int[]` vs `Integer[]`

While `int` is autoboxable to `Integer`, an `int[]` is NOT "autoboxable" to `Integer[]`.

Thus, you get the following behaviors:

```
    List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
    List<int[]> arrs = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

#### Related questions

- [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)

Comment: There are libraries that provide `int[] <-> Integer[]` conversion, or you can use Guava's `Ints.asList(int...)` with `addAll` to a `List<Integer>`, etc. I can elaborate on these points if this is what OP wants to do.

Comment: This is telling me for List<String> : The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Answer (score 3):

```
Collection all = new HashList();
all.addAll(list1);
all.addAll(list2);
```

Comment: is it that addAll cannot be applied to int[]?

Comment: @bhavna: Not according to the signature in the API docs, no: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 1):

I m coding some android, and i found this to be extremely short and handy:

```
    card1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.card1);
    card2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.card2);
    card3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.card3);
    card4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.card4);
    card5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.card5);

    card_list = new ArrayList<>();
    card_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(card1,card2,card3,card4,card5));
```

Versus this standard way i used to employ:

```
    card1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.card1);
    card2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.card2);
    card3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.card3);
    card4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.card4);
    card5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.card5);

    card_list = new ArrayList<>();
    card_list.add(card1) ;
    card_list.add(card2) ;
    card_list.add(card3) ;
    card_list.add(card4) ;
    card_list.add(card5) ;
```

Comment: I would write: "card_list.add(card1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.card1));" if I really need the variables and not just the list.