# Arrays.contains(int) error

Tags: java

can i ask why does the following output FALSE?

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test2();
    }

    private final int[] VOWEL_POS = {0,4,8,14,20};

    Test2(){
        if(Arrays.asList(VOWEL_POS).contains(0)){
            System.out.print("TRUE");
        }else{
            System.out.print("FALSE");
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: See also this Java Puzzler: http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/03/27/array-puzzler/ and this related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `asList` method here returns a `List<int[]>`, which is not what you expect.

The reason is that you can't have a `List<int>`. In order to achieve what you want, make an array of `Integer` - `Integer[]`.

Apache commons-lang has `ArrayUtils` for that:

```
if(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(VOWEL_POS)).contains(0))
```

or make the array initially `Integer[]` so that no conversion is needed

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList` returns a generic type. `int` is a primitive type.

Change the type of your array from `int` to `Integer`:

```
private final Integer[] VOWEL_POS = {0,4,8,14,20};
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `Arrays.asList(VOWEL_POS)` constructs a `List<int[]>` and not a `List<Integer>`. There is no `List<int>` in Java (or of any other primitive type).

Just change your definition to `private final Integer[] VOWEL_POS = {0,4,8,1,20};` and it will become a `List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

Som info [here](http://uncommentedbytes.blogspot.com/2005/12/converting-arrays-to-lists-in-java-5.html)

I think the problem will be that the List contains only a single item, that is actually an integer array.

Since int is a primitive type, you are not calling the asList(Object[]) method but the varargs asList(T... a) method.