# my for loop is rather long - java

Tags: java

My for loop is too long. As demo there is three for loops going on for methodB. Is there a way I could reduce this to a short for loop (one for loop)? Thanks

```
    public class MyMates  
    {

       private static TreeSet<String> myTable = new TreeSet<String>();

       private static String[] names1 = null;
       private static String[] names2 = null;
       private static String[] names3 = null;


       public MyMates()
       {
        super();
        myTable = new TreeSet<String>();
       }


       public  static String methodA(String aTemp)
       {
         String[] names1 = new String[] {"Amy", "Jose", "Jeremy", "Alice", "Patrick"};
         String[] names2 = new String[] { "Alan", "Amy", "Jeremy", "Helen", "Alexi"};
         String[] names3 = new String[] { "Adel", "Aaron", "Amy", "James", "Alice" };

         return aTemp;
      } 



    public static String methodB(String bTemp)
     {

        for (int i = 0; i < names1.length; i++) {
        myTable.add(names1[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(myTable);

        for (int i = 0; i < names2.length; i++) {
        myTable.add(names2[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(myTable);

       for (int i = 0; i < names3.length; i++) {
       myTable.add(names3[i]);
       }
       System.out.println(myTable);

    return bTemp;
   }
```

enter code here

Comment: Imo, the for loops given here aren't bad.  If you had, say, 5 or more names arrays (instead of 3), or more instances of having to do the same thing N times (once for each names array), then it would definitely be worthwhile to refactor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative which uses a 2 dimensional array and two nested loops
(I don't understand parameter and return values in methods A/B)

```
public class MyMates {
    private static TreeSet<String> myTable = new TreeSet<String>();
    private static String[][] names;

    public MyMates() {
        super();
        myTable = new TreeSet<String>();
    }

    public static String methodA(String aTemp) {
        names = new String[][] {
                { "Amy", "Jose", "Jeremy", "Alice", "Patrick" },
                { "Alan", "Amy", "Jeremy", "Helen", "Alexi" },
                { "Adel", "Aaron", "Amy", "James", "Alice" } };

        return aTemp;
    }

    public static String methodB(String bTemp) {

        for (int row = 0; row < names.length; row++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < names[row].length; i++) {
                myTable.add(names[row][i]);
                System.out.println(myTable);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        methodA("");
        methodB("");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't either, but this isn't an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: its assignment. I have been asked to create different methods to do different things. The above is a demo not the actual assignment. The assignment asked for return values. In the next assignment I will be using lists etc, as it should be.

Comment: This is a good answer.  Generally, implementing variables x1, x2, ... xn is doing work that the computer can do for you--specifically, if you want the computer to understand the concept of "N variables of the same type" so that it can iterate through all of them, you need a collection (such as an array), as demonstrated in this answer.

Comment: @dowln: you say this is an assignment, so please tag as "homework"

Answer (score 9):

Actually, you don't need any for loop:

```
myTable.addAll(Arrays.asList(names1));
myTable.addAll(Arrays.asList(names2));
myTable.addAll(Arrays.asList(names3));
```

Comment: yep, but I think it's a kind of homework, so he probably must use the for loop

Answer (score 8):

#### On extract method refactoring

When you have something like this (in pseudocode):

```
doA(x);
doB(x);
doC(x);

doA(y);
doB(y);
doC(y);
```

You can often (though not always) extract `doA/doB/doC` and refactor into a method `doABC` like this:

```
void doABC(o) {
  doA(o);
  doB(o);
  doC(o);
}
```

Then elsewhere you do:

```
doABC(x);
doABC(y);
```

This is called [extract method refactoring](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html).

---

#### On for-each loop

Since 1.5, the for-each loop is added for arrays and instances of `Iterable`. Here's a simple example:

```
    String[] names = { "Alice", "Bob", "Carol" };
    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    // "Alice", "Bob", "Carol"
```

A quote from *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 46: Prefer `for-each` loops to traditional `for` loops*:

> The `for-each` loop, introduced in release 1.5, gets rid of the clutter
>   and the opportunity for error by hiding the iterator or index variable
>   completely. The resulting idiom applies equally to collections and arrays:
>
> ```
> // The preferred idiom for iterating over collections and arrays
> for (Element e : elements) {
>     doSomething(e);
> }
> ```
>
> When you see the colon (:), read it as "in." Thus, the loop above reads as
>   "for each element `e` in elements." Note that there is no performance penalty
>   for using the `for-each` loop, even for arrays. In fact, it may offer a slight
>   performance advantage over an ordinary `for` loop in some circumstances, as it
>   computes the limit of the array index only once.

The `for-each` loop is not applicable to all cases, but when it does, you should always try to use it to improve readability and minimize chances of errors.

#### See also

- [Java Language Guide/foreach loop](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

---

#### On `Collection.addAll`

`Collection<E>` defines [`addAll(Collection<? extends E>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) that can be used to add all elements from one `Collection` to another (assuming it's typesafe).

Moreover, there's [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) that can create a `List` backed by an array of references (not primitives!).

This means that in this case you can do:

```
myTable.addAll(Arrays.asList(names1));
myTable.addAll(Arrays.asList(names2));
myTable.addAll(Arrays.asList(names3));
```

Note that a common pitfall is to pass, e.g. an `int[]` to `Arrays.asList`, and hoping to get a `List<Integer>`. This doesn't work, because while an `int` is autoboxable to an `Integer`, an `int[]` is *NOT* autoboxable to an `Integer[]`.

#### Related questions

- [Arrays.contains(int) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264164/arrays-containsint-error)
- [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)
- [Java noob: generics over objects only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015716/java-noob-generics-over-objects-only)

---

#### On local variables

You've written the following:

```
public class MyMates  {
   private static String[] names1 = null;
   private static String[] names2 = null;
   private static String[] names3 = null;

   public  static String methodA(String aTemp) {
     String[] names1 = ...;
     String[] names2 = ...;
     String[] names3 = ...;

     return aTemp;
   }
```

It needs to be said that the assignments in `methodA` are to locally declared variables `names1`, `names2`, `names3` that shadows the fields with the same names. These variables goes out of scope at the end of `methodA`, and thus serve little to no purpose.

More often than not this is not what you want. You probably intent to assign to the fields instead, i.e.:

```
   public  static String methodA(String aTemp) {
     names1 = ...;
     names2 = ...;
     names3 = ...;

     return aTemp;
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

Implement a method `addNames(String[] names)` and call it 3 times.

This is called the ["extract method" refactoring](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html).

Answer (score 3):

why not use a 2d array?

```
 String[][] names = { {"Amy", "Jose", "Jeremy", "Alice", "Patrick"},
     { "Alan", "Amy", "Jeremy", "Helen", "Alexi"},
     { "Adel", "Aaron", "Amy", "James", "Alice" } };

 public static String methodB(String bTemp)
 {
     for (String[] namesarray : names)
     {
        for (String name : namesarray)
        {
           myTable.add(name);
        }
     }
     return bTemp;
 }
```

---

p.s. the methodA() / methodB() syntax is strange.... you are leaving yourself open to errors if the methodA() or methodB() is called more than once, or something uses myTable before methodA() and methodB() are both called.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one for loop, you can first create an array (or a list) containing names1, names2 and names3.

Then you only have to loop on this new array/list.

Note : reset myTable which is **static** at each new instance (in the constructor) is curious...

Comment: I think the entire class is curious...but you can have a look at his 3 or 4 questions with his examples, it's always the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Make a double loop:

```
String [] [] tableArray = new String [] [] {names1, names2, names3}
  for (int i = 0; i<tableArray.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < tableArray[i].length; j++) {
    myTable.add(tableArray[i][j]);
    } }
```

Or you can perform a better algorithm for your homework, with a single loop, reducing the `O(n^3)` complexity to `O(max(names1.length, names2.length, names3.length))` putting conditions and flags.

good luck with that one.