# random generate character in a string

Tags: java, permutation

i need to generate random character in a String java when user click on button.
for example :if we take cat example i need to disply character in a string like follwing:

CAT,ACT,TAC,TCA

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Comment: sorry i am not understanding what u r asking

Comment: Permutations? is it what you want ?

Comment: i think that should lengthy process

Comment: please clarify your question title and description. You are asking for the way to generate permutation, not random character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Thankq for all finally i got solution for my problem.

```
public String RandomString(String word){

    int no=word.length();
    String temp="";
    String temp2=null;
     while(no>0){
         int genNo=ran.nextInt(word.length());
         if(temp2==null){
             temp2=""+genNo;
             temp=Character.toString(word.charAt(genNo));
             no--;
         }else{
            if(!temp2.contains(""+genNo)){
                temp2=temp2+""+genNo;
                temp=temp+Character.toString(word.charAt(genNo));
                no--;
            }
         }
     }

    if(!temp.equals(word)){
         Log.v("check","temp2 = "+temp2);
         Log.v("check","String = "+temp);
        return temp;
    }else{
        RandomGenerate(word);
    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: This is a very poor solution.  There are several exceptional circumstances where it will enter an infinite loop.  It's also *horrifically* slow, especially for long Strings.

Comment: can u pl suggest me if you have any solution for this

Comment: Using the + operator on Strings is very slow.  Instead, use the [StringBuilder](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class or manipulate the characters directly in a `char` buffer.

Comment: As for your algorithm, the core problem comes with the `temp2.contains` call.  As it is, you randomly generate a number until you find one that's not already been used.  This is slow for long strongs, since it can take a very long time to find the single last unused index is a large range.  In my initial answer above, I instead suggested to keep a list of characters that *haven't* been used yet, then `remove` them until there are none remaining.  This way no random numbers are wasted.

Answer (score 7):

#### On Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm

[Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is a standard algorithm for shuffling. Here's the pseudocode:

```
To shuffle an array a of n elements:
   for i from n - 1 downto 0 do
         j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
         exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

Here's a straightforward Java implementation:

```
static String shuffled(String s) {
    char[] a = s.toCharArray();
    final int N = a.length;
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int j = r.nextInt(i + 1);
        swap(a, i, j);
    }
    return new String(a);
}
static void swap(char[] a, int i, int j) {
    char t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
}
```

Then you can have:

```
    String text = "stackoverflow";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(shuffled(text));
    }
```

This will generate 10 shuffling of the string `"stackoverflow"` ([see also on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/qHBjq)).

---

#### Guava + Java Collections Framework alternative solution

If you have [Guava library](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) installed, then this would be a nice solution. Here are the key facts:

- Guava has [`Chars.asList(char...)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html#asList%28char...%29) which creates a `List<Character>` *live view* of a `char[]`. Modifications to the returned list will affect the backing array (and vice versa).
- [`java.util.Collections`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) can [`shuffle(List<?>)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

We can then combine the two to get the following clean and readable code:

```
import com.google.common.primitives.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AnagramCreator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "stackoverflow";
        char[] arr = text.toCharArray();
        List<Character> list = Chars.asList(arr);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Collections.shuffle(list);
            System.out.println(new String(arr));
        }
    }
}
```

The above will print 10 anagrams of `"stackoverflow"`.

Note that Guava is only used to provide the `List<Character>` *live view* of the `char[]`. A `char[]` does not get autoboxed to a `Character[]` (and vice versa), otherwise `Arrays.asList(T...)` would've been sufficient.

#### See also

- [Java Language Guide/Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

#### Related questions

- [`Arrays.asList()` not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)

Comment: The condition on your `for` statement should be `i > 0`.  A final loop with `i` equal to zero has no effect.  I think the algorithm meant "downto 0" non-inclusive.

Comment: +1.  Nice answer, though it might be a bit much for a new programmer.  I'm interested to see the Guava solution, which actually performs fairly well.  It takes about 50% longer than a good Fisher-Yates shuffle.