# Java Arrays.asList on primitive array type produces unexpected List type

Tags: java, arrays, primitive, autoboxing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)

Apparently the return type of `Arrays.asList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });` is `List<int[]>`. This seems totally broken to me. Does this have something to do with Java not autoboxing arrays of primitive types?

Comment: int is not an Object, but int[] is.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that `Arrays.asList` takes a parameter of `T... array`. The only applicable `T` when you pass the `int[]` is `int[]`, as arrays of primitives will not be autoboxed to arrays of the corresponding object type (in this case `Integer[]`).

So you can do `Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3});`.

Comment: Or simply `Arrays.asList(1,2,3);`

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Note **Integer** instead of **int**. Collections can contain only objects. No primitive types are allowed. `int` is not an object, but `int[]` is, so this is why you get list with one element.