# Is it bug of JDK?

Tags: java, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

This code throw

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

on last line. Is it bug or what? (JDK 7)

```
int ar[] = {1,2,3};
List arList = Arrays.asList(ar);
arList.set(1,8);
```

Comment: piece of advice: "Never blame it on the tool. Almost always it is because of the way you use it."

Comment: 1) *"Is it bug of JDK?"*  Should be *"Is it bug of JRE?"* unless this is a compilation problem. 2) The odds of a newbie finding an API bug against the chances of a newbie making a mistake in code are around 1 in 1,000,000.

Comment: Andrew, are these odds backed by the scientific research data? ;)

Comment: ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException is incorrect usage of array index not a bug in JDK.

Comment: Because [`Arrays.asList(int[]{})` returns `List<int[]>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617567/java-arrays-aslist-on-primitive-array-type-produces-unexpected-list-type) but not `List<Integer>` or even `List<int>`.

Answer (score 9):

No, `Arrays.asList` expects `Integer []`, but you are passing `int[]`. This should fix it.

```
Integer ar[] = {1,2,3};
```

Comment: For reference, using generics would have caught this bug in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is what my inspection says about using a primitive array where a var-arg type is expected.

> Reports any calls to a variable-argument method which has a primitive array in in the variable-argument position (e.g `System.out.printf("%s", new int[]{1, 2, 3})` ). Such a primitive-array argument may be confusing, as it will wrapped as a single-element array, rather than each individual element being boxed, as might be expected.

This means that what you have is a List with only one element in it. And this element is your `int[]`.

And you can't access position `1` in this list since there's only one element. Thus `arList.set(1,8);` will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this kind of error, never use raw types, instead prefer generic types. You want a `List` of Integers?

Try this:

```
int ar[] = {1,2,3};
List<Integer> arList = Arrays.asList(ar); // here
arList.set(1,8);
```

The compiler will show an error in the line where I wrote the comment, indicating that this will not work. When `ar` is a primitive array, `int[]` in your case, then `Arrays.asList(ar)` will return a `List<int[]>`. `List<int[]>` and `List<Integer>` are not compatible. What you have right now is a `List` of `int[]` with 1 entry (at index 0), being your array.

As mentioned before, if you change from primitive `int ar[] = {1,2,3};` to object `Integer ar[] = {1,2,3};` it will work, because the return type of `Arrays.asList(ar)` will be `List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the specified behavior is clear, but there is nothing about this situation in the javadoc for the Arrays.asList() and no check was made for the primitive arrays as input parameters. So, I think this should be treated like a bug.

Method javadoc:

Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.  (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)  This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with {@link Collection#toArray}.  The returned list is erializable and implements {@link RandomAccess}.

This method also provides a convenient way to create a fixed-size list initialized to contain several elements