# Unexpected output when displaying array

Tags: java, arrays, output, bluej

I'm doing an assignment and something is going wrong but I can't quite figure out what it is. We have to generate a random number between 1 and 25 and add it to an array. When adding the random number to the array, we have to make sure that it isn't already in the array, and if it is we have to generate another random number. Here's my code:
    //Variables
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int rndNum;
        int numbers[] = new int[20];

```
    //adds random number to array
    for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
    {
        rndNum = rnd.nextInt(25) + 1; //generates random number
        boolean same;
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, rndNum) >= 0) //checks for number already in array
            same = true;
        else
            same = false;
        //gets another random number if needed    
        while (same == true)
        {
            rndNum = rnd.nextInt(25) + 1;
            same = Arrays.asList(numbers).contains(rndNum);
        }
        numbers[index] = rndNum; //adds random number to array
        Arrays.sort(numbers); //sorts array for checking purposes
    }

    //displays array
    for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
    {
        //prints numbers in table format
        if (index == 4 || index == 9 || index == 14 || index == 19)
            System.out.println(numbers[index]);
        else
            System.out.print(numbers[index] + "\t");
    }
```

This is my output:
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
2   3   4   5   8
12  17  18  19  20
I went through and put break points to see where I was going wrong, but I couldn't see why I was getting a bunch of zeros. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error could be following:

You do:

```
for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
{
    // some computation
    numbers[index] = rndNum; //adds random number to array
    Arrays.sort(numbers); //sorts array for checking purposes
}
```

You enter the new number and then sort the array. But after sorting, there could be a zero at the entry where you just added a non-zero number (because the array is initialized with zeros).

Try not to sort the array while iterating it.

Comment: Ok, I took the iteration out and I'm not getting the numbers anymore, but now the checking doesn't work and I'm getting repeat numbers. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: If you don't sort, you can't use binarySearch. Use the other approach as in your while-loop. Additionally, it is enough to sort the array once you finished your iteration.

Comment: Oh, so if I can't use the binarySearch, what would I use to check if the number is there?

Comment: OH! Ok, so I put Arrays.asList(numbers).contains(rndNum) in place of the binarySearch. Is there something else that I need to do, because I'm still getting repeat numbers

Comment: Yes. Change `int numbers[] = new int[20];` to `Integer numbers[] = new Integer[20];`. Reason is that `Arrays#asList` has a really strange behavior on primitives, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617567/java-arrays-aslist-on-primitive-array-type-produces-unexpected-list-type. I was not aware of that. `Integer`s are not primitive, so the method does what you expect is to do...

Answer (score 0):

If you need a set of random values, why wouldn't let a standard set to make all the job?

```
    java.util.Random rnd = new java.util.Random();
    java.util.Set<Integer> values = new java.util.LinkedHashSet<>();
    while (values.size() < 20) {
        values.add(rnd.nextInt(25) + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(values);
```

Then copy the set to an array if you prefer.

Comment: We haven't learnt about that in class, so I don't know how to use it. We just learnt about arrays, so we're practicing with arrays. Thank you for your input though.