# Collections addAll method for a set of unique values

Tags: java, collections, time-complexity

I am trying to find number of unique characters in a String.  Solution have to be as efficient (time complexity O(N); very big arrays; in general Big O) as possible.  I have decided to do it this way (if you have any better solution please let me know).  The only problem is that when I try to run it it always says there is only one distinct value.  It seems there is a problem with the `Collections.addAll` method (maybe am using it wrong).  Please let me know how to fix it.  It seems it is only taking first character in an array.  Thank you.

```
    String ds = "acvdgefav";
    char[] sa = ds.toCharArray();   

    for (int i=0; i<sa.length; i++)
        System.out.println(sa[i]);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(sa.length);
    System.out.println();

    HashSet hs = new HashSet();
    Collections.addAll(hs, sa);
    for (int i=0; i<hs.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(sa[i]);
    System.out.println();
    int z = hs.size();
    System.out.println(z);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use generics as it would pick up a bug in your code, as would using a debugger to step through your code.

The most efficient approach would be to use a BitSet.  This is likely to be 10x faster than using a HashSet, but would have the same time complexity.

Comment: Please be more specific how to use BitSet with this code.  I tried generics however addAll methods rejected when I tried to put HashSet<Character> into it.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { bitSet.set(str.charAt(i)); } return bitSet.cardinality();`

Answer (score 0):

I think using `Collections.addAll` like that will simply add the array itself to the set, not its characters. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should).

```
import java.util.*;
class a{
    static <T> void f(T...a){
        System.out.println(a.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println(a.length);
        System.out.println(a[0].getClass().getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        f(1,2,3);   
        f(new int[]{1,2,3});
        f(new Integer[]{1,2,3});
    }
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.Integer[]
3
java.lang.Integer

int[][]
1
int[]

java.lang.Integer[]
3
java.lang.Integer
```

Basically a variable arguments method taking a generic array will end up with an `Object...`, implemented as an `Object[]`, which isn't compatible with `int[]`, so the `int[]` gets boxed.

Also, this:

```
for (int i=0; i<hs.size(); i++)
     System.out.println(sa[i]);
```

is wrong. There is no relationship between `i` and characters in `sa`.

Comment: Well what I tried to do was to use the set specification (no duplicate elements) and simply add all elements from the array into a set (duplicates wouldn't be added) so in short only distinct values would be there.  Then use size() and I got it.  You are right about the line (copy-paste eh) Iterator i = hs.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext())
            System.out.println(i.next()); but then it returns some irrelevant value.  I checked both Collections.addAll() and Arrays.asList() only thought this way would be more efficient

Comment: I was wrong about `Arrays.asList`, I think the same thing happens.

Comment: then I will need to downgrade you;)