# indexOf int array elements

Tags: java

I have this code is to find the `indexOf` 3 elements in `array`, so I used `java.util`.. etc, but it gives me that there I mistake the result is -1, how to avoid this wrong answer, and is there another way to write this code

```
int array [] = {1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1};
for(int counter = 0 ; counter < 3; counter++)
    System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n",java.util.Arrays.asList(array).
        indexOf(array[randomNumbers.nextInt(10)]),array[randomNumbers.nextInt(10)]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use wrapper class of "int"

```
    SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();

    Integer array[] = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 };
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++)
        System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n", java.util.Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(array[randomNumbers.nextInt(10)]), array[randomNumbers.nextInt(10)]);
```

**(Edit - 02.03.2014)**

Hi, my first answer was wrong, check the new one:

```
SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();

/**
 * I don't know why but when you create an array with only primitive
 * contained "unnamed block" like "Integer array[] = {1,0,1}". JVM
 * associate same referance variables with same values like "Integer
 * array[] = {@34, @554, @34}". That is why i use "new Integer"
 * constractor for each integer as follows:
 */
Integer array[] = new Integer[] { new Integer(1), new Integer(0),
        new Integer(1), new Integer(0), new Integer(0), new Integer(1),
        new Integer(1), new Integer(0), new Integer(1), new Integer(1) };

int ran, i;
for (int counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
    ran = randomNumbers.nextInt(10);
    i = 0;
    /**
     * "List.indexOf" method uses "object1.equals(object2)" method, this
     * method compares "values" of wrapper classes, but in your case
     * we have to compare referances, so with nested "for" loops we
     * check that:
     */
    for (Integer integer : array) {
        if (integer == array[ran]) { // "==" operator checks referances is same
            System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n", i, ran);
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: because when you pass as "...indexOf(array[randomNumbers.nextInt(10)])" 'int' automacally converted to Integer. This new "Integer" object is different then you add previously.

Comment: No, actually, the problem is with calling `Arrays.asList` on an array of primitives (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should )

Comment: @trutheality my first answer was wrong; check the new one!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I've got the answer, but try breaking up your code into readable lines. And your original array should be `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`.

Note that `Arrays.asList(int[])` creates a `List<int[]>`.

```
    Random randomNumbers = new Random();

    Integer array [] = {1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1};
    for(int counter = 0 ; counter < 3; counter++)
    {
        int randomItemFromArray = array[randomNumbers.nextInt(10)];
        List<Integer> listOfInts = Arrays.asList(array);
        int indexOfRandomItem = listOfInts.indexOf(randomItemFromArray);

        System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n", indexOfRandomItem , randomItemFromArray);
    }
```

This might help.

Comment: you do not even need to use `List.indexOf()` if you take `randomNumbers.nextInt(10)` into a variable.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale I think the aim of the exercise was to use `List.indexOf()`. Your edit has changed my answer.

Comment: @vegemite4me : I should kept both ways. Sorry I retained it back :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the `int[]` array itself because when you use any primitive array and convert it to a `List using Arrays.asList()` it will return a `List<int[]>` not `List<Integer>` hence the issue occurring with your code. to resolve create `array of Integer (Wrapper class)`

```
Integer[] array  = {1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why your code fails:

This is relevant:
[Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)

You call `Arrays.asList` on an `int[]`. This does not produce the expected result because `Arrays.asList` is made to work with an array of `Object`s, not primitives. The result is a list of one element, that element is your `int[]` array (because an array of primitives *is* an `Object`, like any other array).

The solutions:

- You already know your index. You're setting it. No need to look it up. Save it in a variable. I love short code, but sometimes short code is worse and runs slower than slightly longer code. NBD if you didn't fit the entire program on one line. -OR-
- If you still think you need an index lookup, use an array of integer objects (`Integer[]`).