# How to shuffle the contents of an array

Tags: java, arrays, random, shuffle

so my program is supposed to access a text document then do all that jazz that currently works. The only problem that I can't figure out is how to shuffle the contents of an array without having them end up on top of each other. Both internets and multiple tries with random and for loops have been unfruitful. here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class lab_6 {
public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //reads from keyboard
    System.out.println("What is the name of your file. ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(name));// Open text file
    System.out.println("how many names are in your array");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    String[] names = new String[num];    
    for (int index = 0; index< names.length; index++)
    {
        names[index] = reader.nextLine();// Gets a line while there is one 
    } 
    System.out.println("\nOriginal List");
    printList(names);
    System.out.println("\nShuffled List");
    shuffle(names);
    printList(names);
    System.out.println("\nSorted List");
    Arrays.sort(names);  // this is a built in method
    printList(names);
    System.out.println("What name are you looking for");
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in); //reads from keyboard
    String find = input1.nextLine();
    int index = search(names,find);
    if(index == -1)
        System.out.println("The name was not there");
    else
        System.out.println(find+" was found at position "+index);
    System.out.println("The average length of all the names is "+averageLength(names));
}
public static void printList(String[] array) // print the list of names numbered
{
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println((i+1)+") "+ array[i]);
    }

}
public static void shuffle (String[] array) // mix-up the array
{


}
public static int search(String[] array, String find) 
{   
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {

        if (array[i].equals(find) ) return i;

    } 
    return -1;
}
public static double averageLength(String[] array) //return the average length of the names 
{       
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        int l= array[i].length();
        sum +=l;
    }
    int average = sum/(array.length);
    return average; 

}

}
```

Comment: What about reading the data(an index) randomly, instead of shuffle the array?

Comment: how would i go about that? @parsaporahmad

Comment: how about using an ArrayList  http://stackoverflow.com/a/716619/2399024

Comment: Note: with Java 7 you can use `Files.readAllLines()`, this will read all lines from the input file and put them all in a `List<String>`

Comment: Several answer suggest using collections, and it's true that there's a ready-made shuffle there, but it's just using Fisher-Yates under the covers and a collection is probably overkill if you already have your data in an array. On the other hand, using the tested version in the Java Collections API means one less thing you might get wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String[] names = ...;
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(names));
// done
```

Note that `Arrays.asList()` returns a modifiable (but fixed-length) list, backed by the array, and not a copy of the array. So the array will be shuffled.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the Fisher-Yates shuffle (Knuth algorithm P):

```
private Random rand = new Random();

public static void shuffle(String[] array) { // mix-up the array
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        int j = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
        String temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

See:

1. Knuth, D. 1969, 1998: Seminumerical Algorithms 1st & 3rd Eds. The Art of Computer Programming Series, Volume 2, p. 125.
2. Fisher, Ronald A.; Yates, Frank (1948) [1938]. Statistical tables for biological, agricultural and medical research (3rd ed.). London: Oliver & Boyd. pp. 26–27.
3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520212/636009

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Collections` class, with the `shuffle` method. The documentation is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

**Example**

```
int[] values = {1,2,3,4,5};

List<Integer> valuesList = Arrays.asList(values);

Collections.shuffle(valuesList);

// valuesList is shuffled.
```

Comment: Except that this is java, there's no such thing as an `Int`, and `asList` messes up big time with primitive arrays.

Comment: @trutheality But there is the `Integer` object wrapper class for the primitive `int`. Very helpful for primitive `List`s.

Comment: @AndrewG Except it won't auto-box an array of `int`s. You need to give `asList` an array of `Integers` to get a `List<Integer>`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should?lq=1

Comment: @trutheality I didn't say that it would auto-box. But you said that there is no Java object representing an integer, which is incorrect. This answer is still incorrect, and your logic in the second comment is correct.

Comment: @AndrewG No, I just said there's no `Int` I didn't mean that there's no primitive wrapper. Also I just noticed that the array declaration syntax is wrong.

Comment: @trutheality Ok, fair enough. And hmm? `int[] values = {1,2,3,4,5};` is valid code...