# How to can i use integer in ArrayList?

Tags: java

When i replace EmpNo(Integer) to EmpName(String) its working properly. My code is not working for Int. If i search a string in my Array its working but when i search Integer in my array, the ouput is Employee Number not Found!!

```
int EmpNo[]=new int[a];

switch(a){
    case 1:
        System.out.print("Enter Employee Number:");
        number = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int y = Arrays.asList(EmpNo).indexOf(number);
        if(Arrays.asList(EmpNo).contains(number))
        {
            System.out.print("Employee Number: "+EmpNo[y]+" \nEmployee Name "+EmpName[y]+" \nSalary "+Salary[y]+"");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Employee Number not Found!!");
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: how are EmpNo and number defined

Comment: int EmpNo[]=new int[a];

Comment: is indexOf returning -1? why not just check the condition y!=-1 in the if?

Comment: There is no need to use contains() when indexOf() is already used before. Value of y can tell you if number is present in EmpNo or not. if y == -1, employee not found else found at location y.

Comment: I'm not sure of this - but I think the issue is that when you pass `int[]` to `asList` it's treated as a single element; because it can't be cast to `Integer[]` or `Object[]`.

Comment: @DavidWallace You are right, `int[]` will be converted to a singular Object

Comment: Yeah, I thought so.  Which means you've got a singleton list, whose only element is an `int[]` - and you're trying to find an `Integer` in that list.  Nothing will ever be found by `contains` or `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Wallace has pointed out the `int[]` does not autobox to `Integer[]` but will be automatically converted to a singular Object.

Define empNo as

```
Integer [] empNo = new Integer [a] ();
```

Also if `indexOf` is -1 then `contains` will also be false.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int EmpNo[]=new int[a];
```

to

```
Integer EmpNo[]=new Integer[a];
```

Also there is not need to use contains() when indexOf() is already used before. Value of y can tell you if number is present in EmpNo or not. if y == -1, employee not found else found at location y.

Answer (score 0):

`EmpNo` is an array of primitive integers. A `List<>` cannot store primitive data types. It needs `Integer`s instead. So when you do:

```
Arrays.asList(EmpNo)
```

it returns a `List<int[]>` instead of a `List<Integer>`. So the `contains` and `indexOf` obviously do not match for an int.

If you can change the type of `EmpNo`, the simplest solution is to declare it as:

```
Integer[] EmpNo = new Integer[a];
```

Notice the `Integer` instead of the `int`. This should work correctly. If you cannot change the type of `EmpNo`, you will need to use some other methods as given here:

[Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)

Comment: Nothing's wrong with this answer.  I suspect the downvoter misread it.  It happens sometimes.

Answer (score -2):

.contains() will treat the argument inside it as string.so,try using something like

```
if(Arrays.asList(EmpNo).contains(new Int (number))
```

Comment: what is a `new Int` ?