# Java 8 fill array with supplier

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

Is there a way to fill an array using java 8 [`Supplier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) ?

I would like to write:

```
Supplier<Object> supplier = () -> new Object();
Object[] array = new Object[size];
Arrays.fill(array, supplier);
```

Note:
I know i could write my own method.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In case you want to ***create new array*** filled with results generated by Supplier you can use

```
Object[] array = Stream.generate(supplier)
                       .limit(arraySize)
                       .toArray(); // will generate new *Object[]* array
```

For different types than `Object[]` you can use `toArray(IntFunction<YourType[]> generator);` like `toArray(YourType[]::new)` ([credits to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077203/java-8-fill-array-with-supplier/25077583?noredirect=1#comment39016740_25077786) [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)).

```
String[] array  = Stream.generate(supplier)
                        .limit(10)
                        .toArray(String[]::new); //now *String[]* array will be returned
```

Streams also allow us to work with most "popular" primitive types which are `int` `long` and `double`. For instance we can use `IntStream#toArray` to create `int[]` holding elements from `IntStream`. To "fill" `IntStream` with elements from supplier we can use `IntStream.generate(intSupplier)` like

```
int[] array = IntStream.generate(()->1)
                       .limit(5)
                       .toArray(); //returns `new Int[]{1,1,1,1,1}
```

---

In case when you want to fill ***already existing array*** with data from Supplier see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25082456/1393766) posted by [Stuart Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441122/stuart-marks) based on `Arrays.setAll(array, supplier)` which aside from handling arrays of objects also supports *some* arrays of primitive types: `double[]` `int[]` and `long[]` .

**Other alternative** is to use *creative* solution from [@Hogler's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077203/java-8-fill-array-with-supplier/25077786#comment39019224_25077786):

```
Arrays.asList(array).replaceAll(x -> supplier.get()); 
//you can even overwrite a range using `subList`
```

just be aware that `Arrays.asList` is designed to work with arrays of reference type (non-primitive ones), so it will not handle "properly" arrays like `int[]` as explained by Jon Skeet in answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1467940.

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what i am looking for. I gave my example with `Object` but what if i want to use another type like `Integer` or `Date` ?

Comment: @gontard: For generating an array of `MyType`, use `toArray(MyType[]::new)`

Comment: Ok. Could you add this alternative to your answer ? A last question: is it possible to do the same thing with a generic type ? I know it is not possible to create an array of generics but may be...

Comment: As a remark, you can fill an already existing array in the following “creative” way: `Arrays.asList(array).replaceAll(x->supplier.get());`. You can even overwrite a range using `subList`.

Comment: Using the creative way one should be careful with primitive types.
First example is ok:  
`System.out.println(Arrays.asList( new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5}));`
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Second example is a list containing one single element which is the whole array:  
`System.out.println(Arrays.asList( new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}));`
`[[I@53b32d7]`

Answer (score 32):

In [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-) there is

```
<T> void Arrays.setAll(T[] array, IntFunction<T> generator)
```

This doesn't take a supplier; instead it takes an `IntFunction` whose input argument is the array index being filled. If your objects aren't dependent upon the destination array index, you can disregard the parameter and call a supplier like this:

```
Arrays.setAll(array, i -> supplier.get());
```

There are overloads for arrays of primitives as well as arrays of reference type. There is also a corresponding family of methods `parallelSetAll()` that does the same thing, except in parallel. (It uses streams internally.)

Comment: It would be really lovely if there were an overload of this method, that took a `Supplier<T>` as its last argument, instead of the `IntFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily write your own:

```
public static <T> void fillArray(T[] array, Supplier<? extends T> supplier) {
    for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++)
        array[k] = supplier.get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i should have been more specific in my question. I know i could write method with java.

Answer (score -1):

Alternative to Pshemo's solution you could use map method.

```
Object[] array = new Object[size];
array = Arrays.stream(array).map(a -> new Object()).toArray();
```

Comment: @Pshemo: I got. I thought he wanted a usual filling with same object.

Comment: In this solution array created twice.