# How to collect result of a stream into an array of custom object in Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I have an `List<TestBuilder> testBuilders;`
Test has a function build of type Test

I did `testBuilders.stream().map(Test::build()).collect()`

I want to collect above in `array of Test  i.e Test[]`

I am not sure what would go in `collect function`

Comment: Not really related but: are you sure you want to have list of test builders? Should one builder produce only one test, or one builder should produce N tests? If one builder should generate N tests you could use code like `Stream.generate(someSingleTestBuilder::build).limit(N).toArray(Test[]::new);`

Comment: Possibly related: [Java 8 fill array with supplier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25077203)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the terminal operation [`Stream::toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) which packs the sequence of items into an array. However, you have to define a provided generator [`IntFunction<A[]>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntFunction.html) to allocate the type of returned array:

```
Test[] array = testBuilders.stream().map(Test::build).toArray(size -> new Test[size]);
```

The lambda expression `size -> new Test[size]` should be replaced with a method reference:

```
Test[] array = testBuilders.stream().map(Test::build).toArray(Test[]::new);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
whatever.stream().toArray(WhatEverClass[]::new);
```

to create an array for objects of type `WhatEverClass` based on "whatever" stream of objects of that type. Thus: no need to `collect()` anything.