# Using Arrays.asList to create List from Array

Tags: java, arrays

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t) shows that the code below creates a `List` from an array.

```
double[] features = new double[19];
List<Double> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(features));
```

I'm expecting `list` to contain 19 elements, each of which is 0.0. However, after running the code above, `list` only contains 1 element, which is `[0.0, 0.0, ..., 0.0]`. I'm running Java 6 and not sure if this is related.

Comment: I don't know why your question was re-opened. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't** use [Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Your `features` is empty. And you can't make a collection of a primitive type `double`, you need `Double`.

```
Double[] features = new Double[19]; // <-- an Object type
Arrays.fill(features, Double.valueOf(1)); // <-- fill the array
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(features));
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Diamond operator `<>` was introduced in Java 7 but OP states that he is using Java 6

Comment: `Your features is empty.` Not really and filling that array is not necessary for this example. (repost due to evil typo)

Comment: @Tom Or it would be 19 null(s).

Comment: :D right, you had to fix the type to correct the code, already forgot that. But "his" `features` isn't empty :P.

Answer (score 2):

Every array is also an object. You call to `Arrays.asList` creates a List with a single element, which is the entire array. So you are creating a `List<double[]>`, *not* a `List<Double>`. Since you were using a raw type, the compiler did not spot this error and compiled with only a warning message. If you would have typed `new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(features))`, your program would not have compiled.

Comment: I observed that it didn't compile with `new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(features))` but failed to understand what the problem was. Thanks for pointing it out.