# The method asList(T[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am using jdk1.8.0_121 on eclipse kepler (My OS is windows 7), I have created a simple project contained one class with static main method.

When I tried to create a list as follow

`List l = Arrays.asList(1,2);`

I got this error :

> The method asList(T[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the
>   arguments (int, int).

Comment: `1,2` is not an array. It is 2 separate integers

Comment: try `Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2});`

Comment: This seems to be a problem with type inference and auto-boxing. Would `Arrays.<Integer>asList( 1, 2 )` work?

Comment: But 'List l = Arrays.asList(1,2)' It works fine with jdk1.7

Comment: Using Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2}); I got this error "The method asList(T[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (int[])"

Comment: @Thomas I got this error Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)

Comment: @AmalAbidi Then your problem probably isn't with Java 8, it's that you're targeting the wrong java version. Ensure that your project is correctly setup to run with Java 8.

Comment: Can't reproduce, your code works fine: http://ideone.com/H96HuT

Comment: @TheBakker no it is not

Comment: @Thomas I have checked the java version using : `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));`
it shows me in the output : **1.8.0_121**

Comment: " parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater" - that seems to be the problem: you're using Java 8 to build but restrict the compiler to a pre-Java 5 source level and hence auto-boxing, varargs and generics are not supported and thus the compiler complains. Why are you restricting the source level in the first place?

Comment: @Thomas I did not any restrcition or perhaps I did it accidentaly !
Do you know how to eliminate this restriction in eclipse ?

Comment: Check "Java Compiler" in your project settings.

Answer (score 55):

In case anyone else comes across a similar issue, I found that I had this error because I was importing 
`edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.Arrays;`
instead of
`java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: Nice observation. Thank you.

Comment: I logged in to upvote this because I was importing an assertion package. This answer saved me, thanks!

Comment: In my case it was `import org.assertj.core.util.Arrays;` rather than `java.util.Arrays` but your answer pointed me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put an array as the parameter of asList.
like:

```
int[] data = {1,2,3,4,5};
List list = Arrays.asList(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue like wrongly imported `org.javers.common.collection.arrays`
So removed that one and imported from Utils Arrays got

Answer (score 0):

It's very obvious from the error statement itself. You cannot pass primitive values.

Below is the correct syntax (for modifiable list):

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(List.of("apple", "banana", "orange"));
```

Below is the correct syntax ( for unmodifiable list):

```
    List<Integer> integerList = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    List<String> stringList = List.of("apple", "banana", "orange");
```