# How to remove last comma and space in array? Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

guys I was wondering how to remove the extra comma and space from the array? When I run the program it gives me {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, }. What I want is
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Main must stay the same. PrintArray method is the one I need help with.

Referring to duplicate question statement.
This is different because it asks a user for a number and prints the array accordingly. This is not a duplicate question.

```
public static void printArray(int[] myArray) {
    System.out.print("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        myArray[i] = i + 1;
        System.out.print(myArray[i] + ", ");
    }

    System.out.println("]");
}
```

Comment: you can print all elements except the last one and then print the last element seperately

Comment: truncate the last 3 characters and then append "]" back.  Or better yet, instead of blindly appending the `", "`, check the length of `myArray` and the value of `i` to determine if you need to append `", "`.

Comment: I also sometimes build the output in a `StringBuilder`, then just always remove the last space and comma.  `StringBuilder` is just a `char[]` under the hood, so removing two characters from the end is easy.  The resulting code is pretty compact and efficient too.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I suggest your `printArray` method, only print the array.  Having it also initialise the array is a confusing complication missed by some answering the question. You could call the method `initialiseAndPrintArray`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't print it in the first place. Print the comma before the string and only when `i > 0`.

```
public static void printArray(int[] myArray)
{

    System.out.print("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = i + 1;
        if (i > 0)
        {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
        System.out.print(myArray[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

The easy way to do this is just use `Arrays.toString`

```
public static void printArray(int[] myArray)
{
    System.out.print( Arrays.toString( myArray ) );
}
```

Note this prints brackets instead of braces.  In the interest of completeness, if you do implement this yourself, don't forget to check for the array being `null` in addition to other boundary conditions like length = 0.

Here is an example using `StringBuilder`, where I just always remove the last two characters after checking for `null` and length = 0.  If you have a very complicated string to calculate for each item in a list/array, this can be easier than copying the code to make each item outside the loop, and can be slightly faster than checking for `i==array.length-1` each time through the loop.

```
public class MyArraysToString
{

   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      int[] test = { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, };
      printArray( test );
      System.out.println( myToString( null ) );
      System.out.println( myToString( new int[0] ) );
      System.out.println( myToString( test ) );
   }

   public static void printArray( int[] myArray )
   {
      System.out.println( Arrays.toString( myArray ) );
   }

   public static String myToString( int[] a ) {
      if( a == null ) return "null";
      if( a.length == 0 ) return "{}";
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append( '{' );
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         sb.append( a[i] );
         sb.append( ", " );
      }
      sb.setLength( sb.length()-2 );
      sb.append( '}' );
      return sb.toString();
   }
}
```

Comment: Note; rather confusingly, instead of just printing the array OP's code also initialises it.

Comment: Oh, OP's code.  Yeah that's kinda weird.

Comment: The original code has `myArray[i] = i + 1;` which is going to do something different from your code. IMHO your code makes more sense, it just doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: I assume that was just a test case so he could produce output, but yeah he might have meant to also initialize the array too, in which case his question doesn't really match his problem.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that guys, I removed my main method. I thought it would make things easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

I would modify it as such *(printing the comma before the next item, for index > 0)*

```
System.out.print("[");
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  myArray[i] = i + 1;
  System.out.print(((i > 0) ? ", " : "") + myArray[i]);
}
System.out.print("]");
```

Or, in Java 8,

```
System.out.println(
  "[" + 
  Arrays.stream(array)
      .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
      .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
  + "]"
);
```

Comment: `Collections.asList` doesn't work for array of primitive types. You may want to use `Stream.of` or `Arrays.stream` instead.

Comment: Right, I was thinking of `Arrays.asList` (no such thing as `Collections.asList`) while typing it. Hehe :) Thanks! Amended. :)

Comment: Actually I also was thinking about `Arrays.asList` so problem stays. Take a look. If you have `int[] array = {1,2}` and you use `Arrays.asList` you will get `List<int[]>` which will contain one element, array itself. You will not get `List<int>` (since generic types can't be primitive) nor `List<Integer>` (since autoboxing applies only for primitive types, but *any* array is not primitive type, even `int[]`).

Comment: Take a look at [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should), especially this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1467940/1393766

Comment: Had to open an IDE to fix it! hehe. Amended! :) Thanks!