# Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'double[]', 'double

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-stream

I wrote this piece of code:

```
private double[] myArray = {1.0, 2.4, 9.3};

public void testMet(double value){
    if(Arrays.asList(myArray).stream().noneMatch(a -> a==value)){
       ...
    }
}
```

I am getting the error `Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'double[]', 'double`. What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: You cannot compare an array with a scalar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(myArray)` returns `List<double[]>` with `myArray` as its singular element; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1467913/1553851) for details. Use `Arrays.stream()` instead:

```
Arrays.stream(myArray).noneMatch(a -> a==value)
```

Comment: The headliner here is really in the "here for details".  It is not so obvious from the API docs for `Arrays.asList()` that it will have the result it does for arguments that are arrays of primitives.  The pre-varargs docs were much clearer in this regard.

Comment: @JohnBollinger before the introduction of varargs, this kind of error could not happen, as you got a compiler error right when attempting to pass a primitive array to `Arrays.asList`. In retrospect, the retrofitting of `asList` to a varargs method has been considered a design mistake. That’s why `Arrays.stream` is not a varargs method, you can clearly tell apart intent by the choice between `Array.stream(array)` or `Stream.of(some, named, items)`.