# Arrays.asList(word.toCharArray()) does not return a list?

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to convert a **String** into a `Stream<Character>` and encountered this weird thing.

It seems `word.toCharArray()` returns an **Array** but when I try to convert it to a list by `Arrays.asList(word.toCharArray())`, it seems it failed (the output is a whole complete **String**).

What's going on here?

```
   @Test
   public void testCharacterStream() {
       characterStreamNew("HELLO");
   }

   private Stream<Character> characterStreamNew(String word) {
      for(Character c: word.toCharArray()) {
          out.println(c);
      }
      Arrays.asList(word.toCharArray()).stream()
              .peek(out::println)
              .forEachOrdered(out::println);
      return null;
   }
```

And here is the output:

```
H
E
L
L
O
HELLO
HELLO
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1467940/1393766 (based on `int` but `char` vs `Character` have same problem). Will not vote to close as duplicate since "explanation of problem" isn't the same as "solution".

Comment: `List` only support references, not primitives. `Arrays.asList` doesn't autobox the elements of the `char[]` instead its return a List with one `char[]` reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What's going on here?

Here's the signature of `Arrays.asList`:

```
 public static <T> List<T> asList​(T... a)
```

First observation is that `T` must be an reference type.  All Java type parameters are reference types.

Second observation is that `a` is a varargs parameter.  That means that `a` can either be expressed as one or more `T` instances ... OR a `T[]`.

To your example.  It seems that you expect the following expression to produce a list of `char` or `Character`.

```
 Arrays.asList(word.toCharArray())
```

Firstly, `List<char>` is not a valid Java type, because `char` is not a reference type.

Secondly, `List<Character>` cannot be produced because that is not allowed by the signature.   Lets try.  If `T` is `Character`, then the substitution would be

```
   public static List<Character> asList(Character... a)
```

but `Character` actually means `Character[]`, and `word.toCharArray()` produces a `char[]`.  (And the Java language will not convert `char[]` to `Character[]`.)

In fact, what actually happens is that the `T` matches `char[]`, and the result of `Arrays.asList` will be a `List<char[]>`.  And the object that you get will be a list of size 1, with a single `char[]` element which contains all the characters of `word`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `chars()` like so :

```
word.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Outputs

```
H
E
L
L
O
```

---

Your method can look like this :

```
private static Stream<Character> characterStreamNew(String word) {
    return word.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`String.toCharArray()` returns **one object** : an array of `String`.
So here you stream a `List` that contains **a single element** :  an array of String in your code

```
 Arrays.asList(word.toCharArray()).stream()
              .peek(out::println)
              .forEachOrdered(out::println);
```

Whereas the result you got.
So you should try another way to achieve what you are looking for.

In fact, there is no straight way to get a `Stream` of `Character` as it doesn't exist out of the box. The single thing that is the closest is `IntStream` that can handle stream of `int` but also stream of `short` or stream of `char`.

As suggested by YCF_L, you could use `String.chars()` that returns an `IntStream` or alternatively `String.codePoints()`.
The integer representation of the char being not fine for the human reading it is so required to cast the `int` elements to `char` with `mapToObj()` .

Comment: *"`String.toCharArray()` returns one object : an array of `String`."* - Actually ... it returns a `char[]`, not a `String[]`.  (That's what the method name implies, and what the javadoc confirms.)