# Java: HashSet Behavior with Character vs String

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I have the below method which checks if given two strings have atleast one character in common

```
String checkCommonCharacters(String s1, String s2) {
    Set<String> s1Chars = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(s1.split("")));
    Set<String> s2Chars = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(s2.split("")));

    String res = Collections.disjoint(s1Chars, s2Chars) ? "NO" : "YES";
    System.out.println(res);
    return res;
}
```

Above code  works fine but if I change it to a `Character` set it doesnt work. Having the `hashcode()` and `equals()` in `Character` class why `HashSet` is not behaving the same way as of `String` type?

```
Set<Character> s1Chars = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(s1.toCharArray()));
Set<Character> s2Chars = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(s2.toCharArray()));
```

Example:
          Input `s1="abc"`, `s2="dea"` output is `YES` for `String` type
         Input `s1="abc"`, `s2="dea"` output is `NO` for `Character` type

Comment: `toCharArray` doesn't return `Character[]` but `char[]`. See [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1467940) from duplicate question which explains problem with primitive arrays and generics.

Comment: Could you show us the input for "doesn't work?"  I'd like to see exactly what isn't working.

Comment: @markspace for any given input its not working with `Character` type `Set`, input is updated in question