# Confusion in parameter passed in accept function for Consumer while using forEach fucntion

Tags: java

If I call forEach function for a list created as
`Collection.singletonList` or `Arrays.asList`,
the required parameter for the function accept for the Consumer required in the `forEach` function as parameter is type of `int[](for new int[]{})` or `Interger[](for new Integer[]{})`

It seems like every element of the array is passed like an array of size one. So when I'm printing the value like `Arrays.toString(x)` where *type of `x` is `int[]`*, it's working fine

```
Collections.singletonList(new int[] {1, 2, 3})
               .forEach(new Consumer<int[]>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(int[] o) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
});
```

Why the required parameter is of type `int[]` instead of int

Comment: Because you created a singleton list (i.e. a list with only ONE element), and this sole element is of type int[].

Comment: It's strange when an anonymous class is created to implement an interface that was particularly meant to be a functional interface...

Comment: Possibly related: [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1467913) see especially Jon Skeet's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1467940

Comment: @Benoit It behaves same if I use `Arrays.asList()` instead of `Collections.singletonList()`

Answer (score 2):

`Collection.singletonList` creates, as the name states, a list with one element - in your case with an array. What I assume you want to achieve is something like

```
Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).forEach(new Consumer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Integer o) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like `Collections.singletonList` and `Arrays.asList` both create an array of size 1 for each elements of the array. That's must be because of the implementation of those function. I should stick with `IntStream.range(1, 4).boxed().forEach(System.out::println)`.

Comment: No, Arrays.asList creates a list of elements where each element has the type you pass into Arrays.asList. `Collections.singletonList(1)` is a shortcut/simplification for `Arrays.asList(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

The way you build the list is incorrect. You actually create a singleton list (i.e. a list with only ONE element), and this sole element is of type int[].

Note also `Consumer` is intended to be used with lambda or method reference:

```
        Stream.of(1,2,3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I know that that can be done, after all `List.of(1, 2, 3).forEach(System.out::println)` this is another implementation from Java-9. I just wanted to know why is it taking int[] as input.

Comment: Looks like `IntStream.of(new int[] {1, 2, 3}).boxed().forEach(System.out::println)` this must be the only way.