# Why does Arrays.asList() behave the way it does with primitive arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

Here's code + output that shows conversion of `Integer[]` to `List<Integer>`:

```
Integer[] objects = new Integer[]{11, 22, 33};
List<Integer> objectList = Arrays.asList(objects);
System.out.println("object list    : " + objectList.toString());

object list    : [11, 22, 33]
```

Here's slightly different code + output that follows the same path, but for `int[]`:

```
int[] primitives = new int[]{11, 22, 33};
List<int[]> primitiveList = Arrays.asList(primitives);
System.out.println("primitive list : " + primitiveList.toString());
System.out.println("first entry    : " + Arrays.toString(primitiveList.get(0)));

primitive list : [[I@1218025c, [I@1218025c]
first entry    : [11, 22, 33]
```

I encountered this while working on a practice problem. Without thinking about it too much, I expected to be able to create a List from an array. I only noticed it because IntelliJ flagged `Arrays.asList(numbers)` with *"call to asList() with only one argument"* for the `int[]` case. However, since `Arrays.asList()` supports varargs, I might have called it with two (or more) different `int` arrays and would have seen no warning at all (for example: `Arrays.asList(numbers1, numbers2)`).

`Arrays.asList()` converts an array to a `List` of objects, which works as expected when converting `Integer[]` to `List<Integer>`. It makes sense that primitive types like `int` won't work because creating a `List` of primitives isn't allowed, so instead of returning `List<int>` it returns `List<int[]>`. From JLS [4.3.1. Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1): *"An object is a class instance or an array"* – clearly though, in the case of `Arrays.asList()`, there's a subtlety about whether it's an array of *objects* or an array of *primitives*.

Why does it behave this way? Why can't autoboxing work, from `int[]` to `Integer[]`? Why does the Javadoc for [Arrays.asList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) make no mention of this behavior with primitive arrays?

Regarding [Jon Skeet's answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1467940/7294647), specifically: *"There's no such thing as a `List<int>` in Java - generics don't support primitives. Autoboxing only happens for a single element, not for arrays of primitives."* – the answer does not address why generics don't support primitives, nor why autoboxing only happens for a single element, which is the intent of this question.

Comment: See [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1467940/7294647) on the duplicate question for an explanation.

Comment: @JacobG. thanks – I edited the question in response.

Comment: I still think that this question is a duplicate, but I've reopened it so others can answer.

Comment: thanks. fwiw I found several similar questions but they all seemed to be targeted around "how do I get around this behavior". I didn't see any explanations of why the behavior occurs. If an answer is buried in a duplicate somewhere, that'd be great. ;)

Comment: A `List<Integer>` is a completely different thing from a `List<int[]>`. The latter doesn't make much sense in the context of your question, but if it does you should be comparing it to `List<Integer[]>` instead, which behaves identically. What you are seeing is the output of `int[].toString()`, which is not overridden from `Object.toString()`.

Comment: thanks @user207421 and @JacobG. – I think there are really two smaller questions here that I'll research separately and possibly make one (or two) new specific questions. for now, I've got a few things to dig further into (autoboxing, implementation of `Arrays.asList()`, `int[].toString()`). cheers.