# java Cannot resolve method 'contains(int)'

Tags: java

This code block prints "not contains" and i don't know why, can somebody help me ?

```
private static final int[] YEARS = new int[] {
        1881, 1893, 1900, 1910, 1919, 1923, 1930, 1932, 1934, 1938
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year = 1919;
    System.out.println(YEARS);

    if (Arrays.asList(YEARS).contains(year))
    {
        System.out.println("Contains");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not contains");
    }
    // Write your code here below
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)

Comment: Additionally, please fix question title, it has nothing in common with the actual question you are asking.

Comment: there is no method `asList(int... )` (receiving primitive values), only `asList(T...)` and the generic type  `T` cannot receive primitives, so it is creating a list with a single object, the whole (int) array itself || you can use `Arrays.binarySearch(int[], int)` if the array is sorted; or use `IntStream.of(YEARS).anyMatch(y -> y==1919)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(YEARS)` will result in a `List<int[]>`, you will not find a single `int` in there using the `contains(int)` method of a `List`…

You probably expected a `List<Integer>`, which you can get by

```java
List<Integer> years = Arrays.stream(YEARS).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The resulting `List<Integer>` can be checked for the presence of a single `int` using the `contains` method because it is a list of integers contrary to the list of arrays of integers produced by `Arrays.asList(YEARS)`.

Answer (score 1):

that's because you are using `int`
in your arraylist when you should be using `Integer`

`int` is a primitive type and doesn't work with Arraylist which requires a non-primitive type

change `int` to `Integer` and that code should work