# Can't print simple HashSet<int[]> elements in java

Tags: java, hashset, println

I try to print simple HashSet in java 20 without success what am i missing here ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a1 = {1,3,6,8,10,11,14,17,21};
    int[] a2 = {2,4,8,9,12,14,15};

    
    HashSet<int[]> result = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a1));
    Iterator<int[]> it = result.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
      System.out.println(it.next());
    }
    System.out.println(result.toString());
   

  }
}
```

Result is :
[image]

Comment: You *are* printing the contents of the HashSet. What different output did you expect?

Comment: i like to print all the elements of the set , but looks like my conversion of array to set it not right

Comment: do you really want a `HashSet` containing arrays, or should it be a `HashSet<Integer>`? Arrays are not the *best* elements to be maintained in a `HashSet` since, for example, arrays do not extend `hashcode()`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/85421), anything that is represented in textual form is better posted as *textt*  (15 years, 30K reputation??!!)

Comment: also check [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1467913/85421)

Answer (score 0):

To get a string representation of an array you can use `Arrays.toString()`:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a1 = {1,3,6,8,10,11,14,17,21};
        int[] a2 = {2,4,8,9,12,14,15};

        Set<int[]> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(a1);
        set.add(a2);

        for(int[] entry : set) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(entry));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15]
[1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11, 14, 17, 21]
```

Comment: wait the end result is to that the set not to hold array in each element . 
but convert the elements of the array to set

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question, and this time try to frame the question correctly.

Comment: You might also do `Set<Integer> allInts = result.stream().flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: no easier way ? im not going to remember this

Comment: StackOverflow in a nutshell...