# Add each element in array to a list

Tags: java, arrays, list

What's the easiest way add all of the elements in an array to a list?

e.g.

```
List<Byte> l = new ArrayList<Byte>();
//Want to add each element in below array to l
byte[] b = "something".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Is there some utility method or something that does this. I tried to use addAll, but that wants to add the actual array to the collection.

Thank you.

EDIT:

To clarify, I do want to do this with byte[] because I am going to eventually convert the list back to a byte[] and feed it into MessageDigest.update(). Does that help clarify?

EDIT 2:

So it seems like `List<Byte>` is bad; very bad. What data structure would be recommended if I am basically adding arrays of bytes (I am making a hash of some some SALTS and user information) to feed into MessageDigest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `byte[]`, you're in trouble. `Arrays.asList` won't work because you've got a `byte[]` rather than a `Byte[]`.

This is one of those "primitive vs class" problems. You can probably find 3rd party collection libraries which support this (such as the [Apache Commons Lang project](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)), but I don't believe there's anything out of the box. Alternatively, you could always just write the code yourself:

```
List<Byte> l = new ArrayList<Byte>();
for (byte b : "something".getBytes("UTF-8"))
{
    l.add(b);
}
```

Note that this is a pretty horribly inefficient *storage* format for a sequence of bytes. Even though autoboxing will ensure you don't create any extra `Byte` objects, you're still going to have 4 or 8 bytes per element, as they'll be references. It's very rare for a `List<Byte>` to be appropriate - are you *sure* you need it here?

If you're *actually* dealing with classes, e.g. you've got a `String[]` and you want a `List<String>` then you can use `Arrays.asList()`:

```
String[] array = ...;
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

That will return a read-only list wrapping the array though - if you want a *mutable* list, you can just pass that wrapper to the `ArrayList` constructor:

```
String[] array = ...;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: Perhaps a ByteBuffer or ByteArrayOutputStream is a better choice.

Comment: Those damn Java generics and wrapper types! Anyhow, if you're not shy of throwing in some useful libraries, check out [this answer using apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1974363/1321716)

Comment: Given the title, I'm guessing byte is just an example

Comment: I added some clarification, thanks for all the input, and I rarely work with Bytes so I can change the data structure if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want to add every element one at a time in a loop, you can use Apache commons' [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) to convert the primitive array into an Object array, then use `addAll()`:

```
byte[] b = "something".getBytes("UTF-8");
Byte[] bArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(b);

List<Byte> l = new ArrayList<Byte>();
l.addAll(bArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just don't think its worth adding the project, when I am just going to use it once.