# Partially filled array, deleting duplicate array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am doing one exercise in Absolute Java.
**The Question is**: Write a static method that has a partially filled array of characters as a formal parameter and that deletes all repeated letters from the array. The method should have two formal parameters: an array parameter and a formal parameter of type int that gives the number of array positions used. When the letter is deleted, the remaining letters are moved one position to fill in the gap.

What I think of is using hashset, it should be the most easiest way.
And another way that I am thinking is converting array to list , deleting the duplicates element and then transfer it back.
**Here is a problem for me:** how to write that code??  (why I am asking it?)

```
public static char[] deleteRepeats(char[] array, int size)
{
    ArrayList<String> newarray = new ArrayList<String>();
    newarray = Arrays.asList(array);
}
```

it says type mismatching, how can I correct the code?

**Another question is:** Back to the initial question, how to use partially filled array to implement it?

Comment: `newarray = Arrays.asList(array);` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov I am trying to convert the list of char to arraylist, then I can delete repeated element.

Comment: Have you defined `newarray` before?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov what's your meaning here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754294/convert-an-array-of-primitive-longs-into-a-list-of-longs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> newarray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Is an array list of Generic type String. However your parameters are of `char` type. Therefore they are not interchangeable. That's whats throwing the `Type Mismatch` error.

You are right using a `Set` is the easiest way to implement it. However I don't know whether the exercise wants you to manually do the work.

However you if you cannot use the wrapper class `Character` and must use the `char` type then you must do manual conversion if you are going to get a `Set` to do your replacement work for you.

EDIT:

You cannot use `Arrays.asList()` method to get a list like that. That method takes java objects as arguments not primitive types. And when you pass the `char[]` the only object it sees is the array itself.

So the result is a `List<char[]>` since generics do not support primitive types.

Comment: thanks, after changing the method signature to deleteRepeats(Character[] array, int size), the problem is resolved

Comment: OK. But you should consider doing it the manual way since I think that's what the exercise was about...