# Create a arraylist of bytes by a inputstream

Tags: java

I want to get a `inputStream` source from a file, and put this as a `Byte` in a `ArrayList`.

But I didn´t find any thing about this.

Can someone help me?

Comment: _But I didn´t found any thing about this._ Read _all_ of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) and _all_ of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`Files#readAllBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29):

```
 byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

The conversion to a `List<Byte>`, if you really need it, can be done [with a simple loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/754324/829571).

Comment: Might be worth adding a note about `Arrays.asList(Files.readAllBytes(path))` since he wants an `ArrayList`.

Comment: That would return a `List<byte[]>` with one element.

Comment: But I want the inputStream, because its a file from in e-mail.