# Java List Object instead of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, list, file-handling, listobject

I hava a Java map like this:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

And I am performing following operation on it:

```
data.put("case_ids", new int[] { 31527 });
```

Where case_ids is one of the attribute of 3rd party API. However, that API throws `incorrect API request error` and suggests me to use List object instead of an Array for:

`data.put("case_ids", new int[] { 31527 });`

Not an expert of List, any suggestions? Like `data.put("case_ids", new List[] { 31527 });` ?

***EDITED***: Extending my current question (to avoid repost or similar question). What if I have huge set of values for above put operation and want to create a list of known values. I do not feel that it is a correct way to mention the list of values separated by commas like 31527, 31528, 31529, 31530, 31531,..etc. I would rather store this somewhere and just call that as a input here - `data.put("case_ids", new int[] { input });`. Also, is that possible to do without a file? Just want to avoid dependency on file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following format

`data.put("case_ids", Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 31527 }))`;

If you have an array of integers the one you have mentioned the comments then you can use

```
int [] cases = { 10,20,30};
data.put("case_ids", Arrays.asList(cases));
```

Comment: What if I want to pass more than 1 int value like `31527,31528` ...I am trying to read from the constants var like: `public static final int[] CASES = {
22445, 22466, 22467, 27765, 27772 };` and then calling `data.put("case_ids", Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { CASES }))` does not seem to work. See my edited question part.

Comment: it should be  Arrays.asList(CASES) thats all

Comment: I am not sure why its not working . Whats the error you are getting ? which java version you are using.

Comment: I am not using Java 8 but 7. Here is what I get: Invalid or incomplete "JSON string in API request."

Comment: This is definitely not a Java error . You could execute the following two lines `int [] cases = { 10,20,30}; Arrays.asList(cases)`  with out any errors ?  we will not be able to help the issues with out seeing the whole code.

Comment: You are right, not the Java error but something with my 3rd party API. I will get back once I have more information.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the simplest way how to create a list from known values is

```
Arrays.asList(31527)
```

That would make your call

```
data.put("case_ids", Arrays.asList(31527));
```

supposing the API accepts a `List` as the value. Without the API documentation or the error message, we cannot tell what it really accepts.

There are other ways how to create List, such as `new ArrayList<>()`, etc., just check out the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and concrete classes which implement the `List` interface.

---

*Update*: If you don't want an external file, I suppose you're fine with having the numbers in the source code. The simplest option is to have them somewhere as a static field

```
public static final int[] VALUES = {1, 2, 3, /*...*/};
```

which you can turn into a `List` (in Java 8) with `Arrays.stream(VALUES).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/754294/2032064)).

I  recommend using [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained) instead where you can create a safer immutable list directly with

```
public static final List<Integer> VALUES = ImmutableList.of(1, 2, 3)
```

If you don't like having all values in the code like this, then you can read them from a resource file, but that would be for another question.

Comment: I just edited and extended my current question (avoiding repost and similar question posting). How do I extend to support multiple values as a part of list? Imagine like 1000 different values and writing them directly here won't be the correct way? Rather some file/other constants class?

Comment: I've expanded my answer. You may get a better advice if you explain your use case more, e.g., what are the numbers, where do they come from, etc.

Comment: If I give array of values in the source code such as data.put("case_ids", Arrays.asList(31527, 31528, 31555));, the API does not throw any error. However, when I create a separate class called Constants.java and store this array like public static final int[] VALUES = {31527, 31528, 31555}; and then call data.put("case_ids", Arrays.asList(VALUES));, I run into error of Invalid JSON Api exception. Is something changing, do I have to cast anything?

Comment: I get this with your updated answer: `method stream(int[]) is undefined for the type Arrays?` Also, does not seem to find `Collectors` - says "Collectors cannot be resolved". Am I missing something?

Comment: You're probably not using Java 8. See the mentioned [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/754294/2032064) for more options how to convert an array to list. Mostly they recommend using some library, either Guava or Apache.

Comment: Yeah, not the Java 8 but 7. So the stream() or your solution would not work if I want to use Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> mList = new ArrayList<Integer>;
mList.add(31527);
data.put("case_ids", mList);
```

Comment: *"Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. **Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better**."* - [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks Oussema, I just edited my question and want to have a support for multiple values in the list.

Comment: the List is an Collection so you can store as many value as you want at one list without caring about size.

Answer (score 0):

List is an interface. Use a concrete class like `data.put("case_ids", new ArraList<Integer>{ 31527 });`

Comment: No, this won't even compile.