# Java Integer Array as a input for Arrays.asList()

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, integer

I have a Java map:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

And I am doing following `put` operation on it by:

```
data.put("case_ids", Arrays.asList(22222));
```

where `case_ids` is the attribute for 3rd party API and it accept int values. Here when I input `multiple int` values in `Arrays.asList()`, the Api request works fine. For example, `Arrays.asList(22222, 1111)` works with no issues. However, there is a case where I will have different 100 int values and it will not be a good way to have all the values directly in the code/method. So, I am thinking of creating a constant.java class and have

```
public static final int[] CASES = { 
        11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555,....
    };
```

in the constants java class. However when I make a call to

`data.put("case_ids", Arrays.asList(Constants.CASES));`, I get the API exception of Invalid JSON request.

I do not use Java 8 and so, stream() function would not work for me. I tried this `Arrays.stream(VALUES).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())` as per [Java List Object instead of an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173477/java-list-object-instead-of-an-array/37173527?noredirect=1#comment61888565_37173527).

Comment: Then, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754294/convert-an-array-of-primitive-longs-into-a-list-of-longs).

Comment: `asList` is defined as `<T> List<T> asList(T... a)`. Since `T` cannot be a primitive, the compiler infers that `T` is an `Integer`, making it `List<Integer> asList(Integer... a)`, which then means that `22222` and `1111` gets autoboxed to `Integer`. If you change your constant to `Integer[] CASES`, then it will work.