# How to prevent changing the value of array or object

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java. When developing a program, I created an object with a constructor with variables as arguments. But when I change the value of the variable after creating the object, my object has the second value instead of the first one. I don't want my object to change the value. What do I do?

```
public class Person {

    public Person(int[] arrayTest) {
            this.arrayTest = arrayTest;
    }

    public int[] getArray() {
        return this.arrayTest;
    }

    public boolean canHaveAsArray(int[] arrayTest) {
            return true;
    }

    private int[] arrayTest = new int[2];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[] {5, 10};
        Person obj1 = new Person(array);
        array[0] = 20;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj1.getArray()));
    }
}
```

My output should be [5, 10], but instead, I am getting [20,10]. I need to get [5,10] even when I change an element of the array as shown above. What should I do?

Answer (score 17):

If you pass the original array to the constructor of `Person`, you are passing the reference to the original array. So any change in `arrayTest` inside `Person` instance will reflect in original array(`int[] array`) and vice-versa.

If you don't want to change the value of elements of original array in `Person` instance then you have two options:

- You can modify the code in `Person` constructor to create a copy of original array using `java.util.Arrays.copyOf` method and then use that copy:

  ```
  public Person(int[] arrayTest) {
      this.arrayTest = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(arrayTest, arrayTest.length);
  }
  ```
- Don't pass the original array to constructor, instead just send a copy of original array:

  ```
  Person obj1 = new Person(java.util.Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length));
  ```

However, I would prefer first approach.

---

If you would like to prevent the value of variable which is of primitive type, you can do so using `final` keyword. Eg:

```
private final int test = 1;
```

To prevent changing the value inside an object you can mark the fields as `final`. A `final` keyword in declaration of object instance means the variable can't be reassigned and doesn't guarantee that the object state won't change if the reference to that object is shared. To prevent changing the state of a particular object, you should mark it's field as `final`.

Comment: I agree with this answer. But from the two options stated here, First option should be the most suitable approach. The reason is, whenever you or someone else is going to use the code, they will not make the mistake mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 8):

There is no such thing as immutable (unchangeable) array in Java.  The Java language does not support this.  As [JLS 4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) states:

> If a `final` variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable will always refer to the same object. **This applies also to arrays, because arrays are objects; if a `final` variable holds a reference to an array, then the components of the array may be changed by operations on the array, but the variable will always refer to the same array.**

The JVM spec doesn't support an immutable array type either.  You can't solve this at the language level.  The only way to avoid changes to an array is to not share the reference to the array with other code that *might* change it.

In your example, you have what is known as a [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction).  You are passing an array to your `Person` class, and the caller is keeping a reference to that array so that it can change it.  To solve this, you can:

- copy the array, and pass a reference to the copy, or
- have the constructor (or a setter for the array attribute) make the copy.

(See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55428214/139985 for example code.)

The second alternative is preferable from an OO perspective.  The `Person` class should be responsible for preserving its own internal state from interference ... if that is your design requirement.  It should not rely on the caller to do this.  (Even if the caller is *technically* part of the same class as is the case here.)

Comment: by the way, about Leaky abstraction, Joel on Software has a relevant blog article https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/

Answer (score 1):

There is no unmodifiable array, but you can make an unmodifiable list:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(5, 10);
```

You will have to change your code to use lists instead of arrays, but this is generally preferable anyway.

---

If you already have an array of a non-primitive type, you can wrap it in an unmodifiable list, like so:

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(array));
```

However, while you can't change the list directly, changing the array will change the list. Moreover, this won't work on `int[]`, but only on subclasses of `Object[]`.

Comment: There is no need to make the List immutable as long as there is no modifier.

Comment: @ChristianH.Kuhn What do you mean? "No need" in what context? What modifier?

Comment: If the only write access to a private field is in the constructor, the field is de facto immutable. P.e. `public class Person {
    private List<Integer> arrayTest = new ArrayList<>();
    public Person(int[] arrayTest) {
            this.arrayTest = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arrayTest));
    }

    public int[] getArray() {
        return this.arrayTest.stream().mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).toArray;
    }
}` where the List IS mutable in theory, but as nobody has access to the List but the class itself, which only changes the List in the constructor, the List is de facto immutable.

Comment: @ChristianH.Kuhn Yes, but then you have to read the entire class to be sure that the list is never modified. At any rate, I was trying to answer the more general question of how to make a list immutable so that you can safely pass it to other methods and be sure they don't change it.

Comment: That’s true. As soon as you expose implementation details, you have to inhibit any unwanted changes to those details. The public interface of the original question demands no such exposition, and so imho proper encapsulation is safe enough to prevent any mutability of a private field. And i think, if a class allows modification of a private field that should be immutable by setters or side effects, the design of the class is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

> In Java, objects/arrays are manipulated through reference variables<sup>#</sup>

When a function is invoked with arrays as their arguments, only a *reference* to the array is passed. Therefore, when you mutate `array` array, the `arrayTest` field also get mutated as they are *referring* to the same address

To override this behavior, you can create a copy of the array in your constructor using <kbd>[`Object.clone()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(Java_method))</kbd> method like:

```
public Person(int[] arrayTest) {
    this.arrayTest = arrayTest.clone();
}
```

<sub># Source: Wikipedia</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a copy of the array to the object, as others have suggested, I would recommend that the Person object's constructor should create a copy. Which means instead of,

```
this.arrayTest = arrayTest;
```

It should be

```
this.arrayTest = Arrays.copyOf(arrayTest, arrayTest.length);
```

This would allow the object to be defensive against malicious code trying to modify arrays after construction and validation by constructor. In fact most IDEs have analysis tools which will give you a warning against saving array reference.

Comment: And also return a copyOf in getArray(), or the caller will have access to the array.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out: The array is passed as a *reference* to the `Person`. So changes that are later done to the array will be visible to the `Person` object. But that's only one half of the problem: You are not only *passing* a reference to the array to the constructor of the `Person`, you are also *returning* a reference from the `getArray` method.

---

Generally speaking, and as StephenC already pointed out in his answer: One important aspect of Object-Oriented design is to properly manage the **state space** of objects. It should not be possible for users of a class to bring an object into any form of "inconsistent state".

And this is difficult with plain primitive arrays. Consider the following pseudocode, referring to the class that you posted:

```
int originalArray[] = new int[2];
originalArray[0] = 12;
originalArray[1] = 34;

Person person = new Person(originalArray);
int arrayFromPerson[] = person.getArray();

originalArray[0] = -666;               // Modify the original array
System.out.println(arrayFromPerson[0]) // Prints -666 - this is unexpected!

arrayFromPerson[1] = 12345678;         // Modify the array from the person
System.out.println(originalArray[1])   // Prints 12345678 - this is unexpected!
```

Nobody knows **who** has a reference to the array, and nobody can verify or track that the contents of the array is not changed in any way. How critical this is becomes more obvious when you anticipate that the `Person` object will be used at different places, possibly even by multiple threads.

Plain primitive arrays in Java do have their justification. But when they appear in the *interface* of a class (that is, in its `public` methods), they should be view with scrutiny.

In order to be absolutely sure that nobody can interfere with the array that is stored in the `Person` object, you'd have to create defensive copies everywhere:

```
public Person(int[] arrayTest) {
    this.arrayTest = arrayTest.clone(); // Store a clone of the array
}
public int[] getArray() {
    return this.arrayTest.clone(); // Return a clone of the array
}
```

But this may be cumbersome. A more object-oriented solution could be to expose a "read-only view" on the **state** that is represented with the array. For example:

```
public Person(int[] arrayTest) {
    this.arrayTest = arrayTest.clone(); // Store a clone of the array
}
public int getArrayLength() {
    return this.arrayTest.length;
}
public int getArrayElement(int index) {
    return this.arrayTest[index];
}
```

<sup>(Of course, in practice, you'd name the methods accordingly, depending on what the array actually *represents*. For example, if it's the ages of the children of the person, you'd call the methods `getNumChildren()` and `getAgeOfChild(int i)` or so...)</sup>

Another option how this can be solved is to expose an (unmodifiable) `List` view on the array. This can, for example, be done with the `asUnmodifiableList` method that is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53032263/3182664).

Answer (score 0):

as you are beginner in java you write following code in constructor but it is better to use clone method as marco13 and rv 7 already explained
and as sourabh bhat explained we can also use Arrays class copyof

the idea behind all of above logic is simple don't pass referance of current object but create clone of object and pass that clone or just copy each content of the object

```
    public Person(int[] arrayTest) {
            for (int i = 0; i <this.arrayTest.length; i++) {
                this.arrayTest[i]=arrayTest[i];

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit 5/5/19: Source code added

As most answers point out, there is no immutable array of primitives in Java. So you have to do some tricks.

1. Pure Java: Make defensive copies. Most answers show how to store a copy of the array that is received as a parameter in the constructor. But only one answer mentions that you also have to return a copy of the internal array with getArray().

```
public class Person {
    final private int[] arrayTest;
    public Person(int[] arrayTest) {
            this.arrayTest = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(arrayTest, arrayTest.length);
    }

    public int[] getArray() {
        return java.util.Arrays.copyOf(arrayTest, arrayTest.length);;
    }
}
```

2. Other internal representation: Store the array as a (mutable) ArrayList, which is based on an array and should have best performance. You have to convert from array to List in the constructor and from List to array in getArray(). There is no need to use Collections.unmodifiableList() (or Guavas ImmutableList<>) as long as you write no method that could modify the List because no one will have access to the List.

```
public class Person {
    final private List<Integer> arrayTest;
    public Person(int[] arrayTest) {
            this.arrayTest = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arrayTest));
    }

    public int[] getArray() {
        return this.arrayTest.stream().mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).toArray;
    }
}
```

3. Let other people do the job. Google AutoValue auto-generates immutable classes. And provides equals(), hashCode() and toString(). Easy to use. My favorite solution.

```
import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;
@AutoValue
public abstract class Person {
    public static create(int[] arrayTest) {
            return new AutoValue_Person(int[] arrayTest);
    }

    public abstract int[] getArray() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happens in memory:

```
Program:                            Stack memory:                Heap memory:
int[] array = new int[] {5, 10};    array -> 0x77a89             0x77a89 {5, 10}
Person obj1 = new Person(array);    obj1.arrayTest -> 0x77a89    No change
array[0] = 20;                                                   0x77a89 {20, 10}
```

As you can see stack memory holds only the address of the object which gets created in the heap memory. So when you change the `array`s value it automatically changes in the `Person obj1` object as well.

To fix this you need to create a `new Object` in memory so that the actual Objects value is copied. To do this we can:

[1] Use the `clone` property of `array`.

```
public Person(int[] arrayTest) {
    this.arrayTest = arrayTest.clone();
}
```

[2] Or we can create our own clone.

```
public Person(int[] arrayTest){
    if (arrayTest == null){
        this.arrayTest = null;
    } else {
        int[] copyArray = new int[arrayTest.length];
        for(int i=0; i<arrayTest.length; i++) {
            copyArray[i] = arrayTest[i]
        }
        this.arrayTest = copyArray;
    }
}
```

Either way a new Object is created in memory and this prevents the object from being shared.