# Why is my List modified when I alter the array it was created from

Tags: java, collections

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"Java", "Champ", "."};
        List<String> list = (List<String>) Arrays.asList(arr); // line 1
        arr[2] = ".com"; // line 2
        for (String word : list) {
            System.out.print(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Can please someone explain me why we get here "JavaChamp.com"?
I thought it shoud be just "JavaChamp." because line 2 after line 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`Arrays#asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) returns the fixed-size `List` backed by the array.

Here is the doc of [`Arrays#asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with `Collection.toArray()`. The returned list is serializable and implements `RandomAccess`.

Comment: Related: [How to prevent changing the value of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55428172/how-to-prevent-changing-the-value-of-variable)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually take a look at the code if you want to understand what's happening. In your case, let's take a look at `java.util.Arrays#asList(T...)`

```java
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... var0) {
    return new Arrays.ArrayList(var0); // notice this
}
```

It returns an inner class called 'ArrayList' (not to be confused with `java.util.ArrayList`, these are different classes, but they do more or less the same thing).

```java
// the inner class
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess, Serializable {
    private final E[] a;

    ArrayList(E[] var1) {
        this.a = Objects.requireNonNull(var1); // directly reuses the array you pass in
    }
}
```

Based on this code, we see that the array is reused. It's also important to note that Java will pass arrays as is rather than as a copy in parameters. What does that mean?

```java
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
modifyArray(arr);
assert arr[0] == 2; // true

void modifyArray(int[] array) {
    array[0] = 2;
}
```

Due to this, we can confirm we will share the array instance across parameters. For that reason, when you mutate the array from your scope, you are indirectly affecting the backing array for `Arrays$ArrayList`.

Comment: "pass ... as is" and "copy in parameters" are usually called [_call/pass by reference_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) and [_call/pass by value_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value).