# Is there any decent way to convert multidimensional array to List<List<T>>?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, java-8, java-stream

when we have to convert single-dimensional array List type, we can simply use `Arrays.asList()`. But in the context of multidimensional arrays, I did not find anything similar to this. I have to manually create a `List<List<T>>` and fill values as per original multidimensional array.
      Is there any decent way to convert between these types? Java 8 way?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(...))`

Comment: if we pass multidimensional array `Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(...))`  it will throw an error `incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Was there a `;-)` missing somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.stream` and map inner arrays:

```
<T> List<List<T>> toNestedList(T[][] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
        .map(Arrays::asList)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This will create a stream of inner arrays, map them to list and collect all inner lists to an outer one.

Comment: Truly elegant. that's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The currently proposed solution creates a new list. This means that the array has to be traversed and memory has to be allocated.

Analogously to [`Arrays#asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-), it could be desirable to not create a *new* list, but only a *view* on the given array instead. This way, even if the array contains 1000000 elements, the memory- and performance overhead of creating this list-view is practically *zero*.

An example of how this could be implemented:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.RandomAccess;

public class NestedAsList
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String array[][] =
        {
            { "This", "is", "an" },
            { "example", "of", }, null,
            { "a", "jagged", "array" } 
        };

        List<List<String>> lists = asLists(array);
        lists.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a <i>view</i> on the given array, as a list where each element is
     * a <i>view</i> on the respective array element. When the array contains
     * <code>null</code> elements, then the list will contain an empty list at
     * this index.
     * 
     * @param array The array
     * @return The list view
     */
    private static <T> List<List<T>> asLists(T array[][])
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(array);
        class ResultList extends AbstractList<List<T>> implements RandomAccess
        {
            @Override
            public List<T> get(int index)
            {
                T[] a = array[index];
                if (a == null)
                {
                    // Could return null or the empty list here...
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                }
                return Arrays.asList(a);
            }

            @Override
            public int size()
            {
                return array.length;
            }

        }
        return new ResultList();
    }
}
```

(By the way: I wonder where you get a multidimensional generic array from. These should be rare nowadays...)

---

*Note:* The answer has been updated, based on a [comment by Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57882319/is-there-any-decent-way-to-convert-multidimensional-array-to-listlistt/57888477?noredirect=1#comment102388334_57888477): It can be beneficial to let the returned list also implement the [`java.util.RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) interface, to indicate that it has constant-time indexed access. Many of the static utility methods in the `Collections` class check whether a given list is `RandomAccess`, and are able to perform their task more efficiently in this case.

Unfortunately, one has to create a new, local class in order to implement the additional interface, but depending on how the resulting class is supposed to be used, this can be worthwhile.

The original implementation of the `asLists` method was this one, which simply returned a new `AbstractList`, *not* implementing the `RandomAccess` interface:

```
private static <T> List<List<T>> asLists(T array[][])
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(array);
    return new AbstractList<List<T>>()
    {

        @Override
        public List<T> get(int index)
        {
            T[] a = array[index];
            if (a == null)
            {
                // Could return null or the empty list here...
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
            return Arrays.asList(a);
        }

        @Override
        public int size()
        {
            return array.length;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: That is inspiring. Just curious - where do you have this idea from?

Comment: @Andronicus It's hard to name a definite "source" of this idea, but it's basically the same as `Arrays.asList` does, for 2 dimensions. More generally: "Letting **anything** that has a size and indexed access appear as a `List`" is one of the ideas behind `AbstractList`. I also used this e.g. in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53032263/3182664 , and some places in my own codebase. The nicest thing is that there is no memory- or performance overhead. (One could argue that with each access, `Arrays.asList` creates a new instance, but this is in turn also only a view, and thus, negligible)

Comment: It’s beneficial to let this class implement `RandomAccess`…

Comment: @Holger That's a valid point (and considering how often I'm using this pattern in my own codebase, it's somewhat embarassing that I overlooked this until now). Unfortunately, one has to define a local class for that, which is a bit clumsy compared to the `return new AbstractList`, but it may indeed be worthwhile. I'll probably have an `AbstractRandomAccessList` soon. Updated the answer with the new implementation and additional information.

Comment: @Marco13 I need to say, that I think every answer of yours (out of more than a thousand) is a little masterpiece. I can get knowledge as well as inspiration from them. I believe they reflect a mind behind them, that I would like to become some day - thoughtful, thorough and comprehensive. I'm really sorry you stopped contributing to the site, but I understand the rationale. If you ever want to come back, be sure you have an audience for your great input.

Answer (score 0):

Above solution is correct but does not handle null rows in the 2D array so I have below solution using `stream APIs` from Java 8 and it will work for null rows and generic arrays as well.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TwoDArrayToListOfList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [][] stringArray = new String[][]{{"John", "Alley", "Neon"}, {null}, {"Huston", "Gary"}, {"Ellen", "James", "Chris", "Jacob"}};
        List<List<String>> stringList = getListFrom2DArray(stringArray);
        stringList.forEach(list -> list.forEach(System.out::println));

        Integer [][] intArray = new Integer[][]{{1,3, 6}, {2, 4}, {null}, {6, 4, 3, 5}, {null}};
        List<List<Integer>> intList = getListFrom2DArray(intArray);
        intList.forEach(list -> list.forEach(System.out::println));

        Double [][] doubleArray = new Double[][]{{1.0,3.9, 6.7}, {2.4, 4.4}, {6.5, 4.1, 3.3, 5.2}, {null}};
        List<List<Double>> doubleList = getListFrom2DArray(doubleArray);
        doubleList.forEach(list -> list.forEach(System.out::println));
    }

    private static <T> List<List<T>> getListFrom2DArray(T[][] array) {
        return Arrays.stream(Objects.requireNonNull(array)).map(row -> Arrays.asList((row != null) ? row : (T[]) new Object[0])).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```